# What is the fastest way to check if two Tbitmaps are the same?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Is there a better way than examine them pixel by pixel?

Comment: Please clarify: If they have different pixel formats (for example pf24bit and pf8bit) and therefore different sizes in memory, but contain the exact same pixels, are they the same or not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can save both Bitmaps to TMemoryStream and compare using CompareMem:

```
function IsSameBitmap(Bitmap1, Bitmap2: TBitmap): Boolean;
var
 Stream1, Stream2: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Assert((Bitmap1 <> nil) and (Bitmap2 <> nil), 'Params can''t be nil');
  Result:= False;
  if (Bitmap1.Height <> Bitmap2.Height) or (Bitmap1.Width <> Bitmap2.Width) then
     Exit;
  Stream1:= TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Bitmap1.SaveToStream(Stream1);
    Stream2:= TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Bitmap2.SaveToStream(Stream2);
      if Stream1.Size = Stream2.Size Then
        Result:= CompareMem(Stream1.Memory, Stream2.Memory, Stream1.Size);
    finally
      Stream2.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Stream1.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  if IsSameBitmap(MyImage1.Picture.Bitmap, MyImage2.Picture.Bitmap) then
  begin
    // your code for same bitmap
  end;
end;
```

I did not benchmark this code X scanline, if you do, please let us know which one is the fastest.

Comment: Some comments: 1) Code isn't exception-safe. 2) I would return False immediately if width or height of the bitmaps differ. Or maybe even if the pixel formats differ, but the question is too vague to tell.

Comment: Nice comments mghie. Ill change the code to test the height and width.

Comment: I dont think I can "allow" others to edit my posts, if I can, please let me know how.
If you post here your suggestions I can edit and mention in my post.

Comment: I just edited it, but wanted to alert you before. +1 for the answer BTW.

Comment: Thank you mghie.
BTW, are you the flamerobin author?

Comment: Well, one of them. Neither the original author nor the main one.

Comment: mghie's comment above asks whether matching pixel format is a specification, but it's easy to add as illustrated in RRUZ's answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, such compares can go wrong when one of the bitmaps has a bit garbage in the alignment bytes/bits between lines. Therefore we always compare the pixeldata with comparemem on a per line basis.

Comment: It would also be interesting to benchmark it against loop tiling. See an example for rotate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848025/rotating-bitmaps-in-code Back then I was quite surprised by the speedup, but that example also writes to an image.

Comment: Stack Overflow wouldn't have provided an option for users to edit other users' answers if it wasn't allowed. It's actually highly encouraged.

Answer (score 14):

Using ScanLine, Without TMemoryStream.

```
function IsSameBitmapUsingScanLine(Bitmap1, Bitmap2: TBitmap): Boolean;
var
 i           : Integer;
 ScanBytes   : Integer;
begin
  Result:= (Bitmap1<>nil) and (Bitmap2<>nil);
  if not Result then exit;
  Result:=(bitmap1.Width=bitmap2.Width) and (bitmap1.Height=bitmap2.Height) and (bitmap1.PixelFormat=bitmap2.PixelFormat) ;

  if not Result then exit;

  ScanBytes := Abs(Integer(Bitmap1.Scanline[1]) - Integer(Bitmap1.Scanline[0]));
  for i:=0 to Bitmap1.Height-1 do
  Begin
    Result:=CompareMem(Bitmap1.ScanLine[i],Bitmap2.ScanLine[i],ScanBytes);
    if not Result then exit;
  End;

end;
```

Bye.

Comment: +1 very nicely composed.  It would be interesting to compare the speed of this versus Cesar's solution.  This has more comparisons, but saves time by not allocate memory.  The question title did specify **fastest**, after all.

Comment: @RRUZ: I agree that this is a good solution if same bitmap means the same memory layout, +1. I'd consider a fast check for equal bitmaps in possibly different formats to be a more interesting problem, though. If a pf24bit or pf32bit bitmap has less than 256 colours it can make sense to save it in pf8bit, but the same bitmap will still be displayed.

Comment: I usually only use pf8bit, and for this it would be ok. I wonder though if alignment bits are checked if you have pf12bit and an odd width. Same for bpp's below 8, but those are planed afaik.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an accurate answer, no. If you need an approximation, you probably could check a selection of pixels. But if you want to find out if the two bitmaps are exactly identical you need to compare the entire pixel and pixel format data.