# Display data in table cells from database table Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display some data from a table and display it in the table cells. I have the following.

**Controller**

```
@data = HospitalBooking.where(:created_at => @date_range)
@stuff = [] 
@stuff[0] = [] 

index = 0 

@stuffs.each do |stuff|
  @rotated[0][index] = stuff.detail0
  index += 1
end
```

Not sure if I have gone about this the correct way also how would I display it in my view

Comment: how did @stuff get data ?

Comment: I looked at the following stack question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128663/display-data-in-columns-not-rows-using-ruby-on-rails and am trying to replicate this but getting some data from my `HospitalBooking` table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood it right, you want to display the result of a query in a html table.

Here is your query, in your controller:

```
@data = HospitalBooking.where(:created_at => @date_range)
```

In your view

```
<table>                         
  <tr>                          
    <th>field1</th>
    <th>field2</th>
  </tr>
<% @data.each do |data| %>       #start loop
  <tr>
    <td><%= data.field1 %></td>  #column field1 in your database
    <td><%= data.field2 %></td>  #column field2 in your database
  </tr>
<% end %>                        #end loop
</table>
```

Comment: That is precisely what I want to do.

Comment: However what I am trying to do is get this data from my hospital booking table to appear in the table cells. I have updated my question further

Comment: if you want to display all data from that table, you can just change the query to: `@data = HospitalBooking.all` . and change field1 and field2 by the columns name.

Comment: I have updated my question to include a full in depth explanation of what I am trying to achieve