# Creating an "inverse" table dynamically with ruby and html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-table

I have the following problem: I need to create a table which will look like this:

[image]

I'm building the table dynamically with ruby and I want to avoid having to write a "each" loop for each table row.

Is there a way to make a table "inverse"? Something like

1. td (user1 row)
2. tr (user1)
3. tr (user1 Name)
4. tr (user1 Age)

Sorry for the horrible formatting... Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: I can't see how you can avoid an each loop to display a table whether by row or column as you need to iterate over the data somehow.  Anyhow, maybe this previous question could help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128663/display-data-in-columns-not-rows-using-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Thanks for the link, that question does have a good solution in it.