# Rotating matrix by N degrees

Tags: c++, c++11, math, matrix, rotation

I have a matrix `A[M][M]` and I want to rotate it `N` degrees relative to the center of the matrix, discarding the values which its new position is outside the original matrix and filling the missing values with zeroes. I am using the following formula to get he new positions:

```
newXPosition = ceil(cos(N*PI/180)*(oldXPosition - M/2) - sin(N*PI/180)*(oldYPosition - M/2) + M/2)
newYPosition = ceil(sin(N*PI/180)*(oldXPosition - M/2) + cos(N*PI/180)*(oldYPosition - M/2) + M/2)
```

However, this is failing at some point. If we look for `newXPosition` and `newYPosition` for `oldXPosition = oldYPosition = 0, M = 32 and N = 90º`, We get `newXPosition =  32, newYPosition = 0`. Taking into account that the dimensions are [0-31], it will not work to just substract one to `newXPosition` because in other occasions it would be newYPosition the variable that will have to be substracted, or even both.

Does anyone know where am I failing?

PS: I have already read a couple of answers regarding [the 90 degrees rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893101/how-to-rotate-a-n-x-n-matrix-by-90-degrees), but my intention is not to rotate the matrix 90 degrees, but `N`.

Comment: cos / sin don't take degrees as arguments, they take [radians](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/cos/)

Comment: If the extend of the image is from 0 to 31 then the true center is 31/2=15.5 -- Alternatively, since you are discarding pixels outside the boundaries, your example is just one such pixel.

Answer (score 1):

If you think as each pixel as a small square you see that their center is at 0.5, 1.5 etc; so add "0.5" to oldXPosition - and subtract it when forming newXPosition:

newXPosition = ceil(cos(N*PI/180)*(oldXPosition+0.5- M/2) - sin(N*PI/180)*(oldYPosition+0.5- M/2)+M/2-0.5)

So, in your case newXPosition would be 31 - not 32, and newYPosition 0.

I would also recommend you to reverse the logic, so instead of figuring out the new positions based on old x and y, you start with the new matrix and for each pixel you find out the old position that corresponded to (which is like rotating -N degrees with your formulas) - and take the value from that one.

Otherwise a "solid" shape might get zeros due to the rotation.

Instead of "ceil" you might do some fancy interpolation.