# Rotate 3 x 3 matrix in C++

Tags: c++

How can I rotate by 90 degrees a 3 x 3 matrix in cpp...

```
//create the matrix
const int MATRIX_SIZE = 3;
int m[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
int last = MATRIX_SIZE - 1;

int count = 0;
int level = 0;


for(int i =0; i< MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j< MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
    {
        m[i][j] = count++;
    }
}

//rotate matrix
   for(int i = 0; i <last; ++i)
    {
        Swap(m[level][i], m[i][last]);
        Swap(m[level][i], m[last][last-i]);
        Swap(m[level][i], m[last-i][level]);
    }
```

I get a lot of 1's added and I do not know where they are coming from.

OUTPUT:

```
------ Original Matrix ------ 
0       1       2       
3       4       5       
6       7       8       
 ------ Rotated Matrix ------ 
6       3       1       
1       4       1       
1       1       1
```

I am using "level" to swal through the inner part of the matrix. Is there any other way to do this using STD?

Comment: `m[level][i]` is being swapped in all three swaps. This can't be what you want. Typo?

Comment: Good chance that `last` is out of bounds based on your loop condition.  If you need help, please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Re: _"Is there any other way to do this?"_ -- you should first focus on fixing the way you've chosen to do it.

Comment: Here's how to figure this out, this always works! Take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down a step-by-step process of doing this, as short, brief sentences in plain English. [Have your rubber duck review your plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write or debug other people's code, on Stackoverflow. We refer such questions to their rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++, and you're done! Have you discussed this with your rubber duck, yet?

Comment: One thing you may wish to consider, alongside other suggestions, is using a template. Something like `<template <typename T, std::size_t N> void rotate_matrix(T matrix[N][N]) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Presented for your consideration. Using templates to infer the size of the matrix as it's passed into functions to print it, and to rotate it 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

In the `rotate_matrix` function, the outer loop iterates over "shell levels" using `sl`. A matrix of 3x3 dimensions has `3 / 2` (or `1`) shell levels that need to be rotated. I've tested with a 6x6 matrix, which has three shell levels.

To avoid repetition, each shell has a dimension of `N - sl * 2`, and we subtract one from that to avoid repetition of work on the corners.

Then we just need to map out the four values that need to be moved on each iteration, and do a four-way swap.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void print_matrix(T m[N][N]) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            std::cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void rotate_matrix(T m[N][N]) {
    for (std::size_t sl = 0; sl < N / 2; ++sl) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N - 1 - sl * 2; ++i) {
            T temp                       = m[sl][sl + i];          
            m[sl][sl + i]                = m[sl + i][N - 1 - sl];
            m[sl + i][N - 1 - sl]        = m[N - 1 - sl][N - 1 -sl - i];
            m[N - 1 - sl][N - 1 -sl - i] = m[N - 1 - sl - i][sl];
            m[N - 1 - sl - i][sl]        = temp;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int m[6][6] = {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6},
        { 7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18},
        {19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24},
        {25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30},
        {31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36}
    };

    print_matrix(m);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    rotate_matrix(m);
    print_matrix(m);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36

6 12 18 24 30 36
5 11 17 23 29 35
4 10 16 22 28 34
3 9 15 21 27 33
2 8 14 20 26 32
1 7 13 19 25 31
```

Answer (score 0):

the swap() fucntion had an typo. got it to work

```
void Swap(int& i, int& j)
{
    int temp = i; 
    i = j; 
    j = temp;
}
```

Also, check this out for other solutions.
[How to rotate a N x N matrix by 90 degrees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893101/how-to-rotate-a-n-x-n-matrix-by-90-degrees)

Comment: A good reason why we need a MRE -- most of our crystal-balls broke years ago. See [How to create a Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And the rest were corrupted by Sauron.