# How can I rotate this list of lists with python

Tags: python

I have a list of list and I need to rotate it ninety degrees. I managed to get the first new row but I couldn't get any of the others so I put the for loop in to a a function and I increased the count by one every iteration but I've just had big mess printed to the terminal.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

How I need to rotate.

```
'''
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....

'''
```

My code

```
def get_row(grid, new_grid, new_row, count):
    for row in grid:
        new_row.append(row[count])
    new_grid.append(new_row)

new_grid = []
new_row = []
count = 0

for x in range(0, 6):
    count = 0
    get_row(grid, new_grid, new_row, count)
    count +=1

for row in new_grid:
    print row
```

Comment: FYI, [How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42519/364696) covers just about every language, [including Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24356420/364696).

Comment: Oh, and [Rotating a two-dimensional array in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8421337/364696) is probably even better targeted; it covers both the how and the why. Also, [this answer to How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/496056/364696) is a better link, since it uses `zip`, not `map(None` which is weird and not portable to Py3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can rotate your list of lists 90° using `zip(*reversed(your_list))` like this:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

print("\n".join(map("".join, zip(*reversed(grid)))))
```

Out:

```
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

Instead of [`reversed(grid)`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) you can use [`grid[::-1]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) which also reverses the outer list, except it creates a copy of your list, which uses more memory (here I'm also using [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html) to show you what exactly your transposed list looks like):

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(list(zip(*grid[::-1])))

[('.', '.', '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '.', '.'),
 ('.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'),
 ('.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'),
 ('.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'),
 ('.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'),
 ('.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '.', '.', '.', '.')]
```

Which if you really wanted lists instead of tuples you could convert them back to list:

```
pprint([list(row) for row in zip(*reversed(grid))])

[['.', '.', '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Comment: Now that we have python3, for simple print of arrays, instead of using `print('\n'.join(array))` I now usually use `print(*array,sep='\n')`

Answer (score 4):

index magic:

```
>>> grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
>>> for i in range(len(grid[0])): #assuming they all have the same length
    print (''.join(x[i] for x in grid))


..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

or to save to a new grid:

```
>>> newgrid = []
>>> for i in range(len(grid[0])): #assuming they all have the same length
    newgrid.append([x[i] for x in grid])


>>> newgrid
[['.', '.', '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

or one line:

```
>>> newgrid = [[x[i] for x in grid] for i in range(len(grid[0]))]
>>> newgrid
[['.', '.', '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Instead of just rotating the image it transposes it (meaning it rotates and then **mirrors it**). It just looks right in this case because the image is symmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.rot90`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) can do that and is fast for large matrices such as images:

```
import numpy as np

grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.'],
        ['0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
grid = np.rot90(grid, k=3)   
print(grid)

# [['.' '.' '0' '0' '.' '0' '0' '.' '.']
#  ['.' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '.']
#  ['.' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '.']
#  ['.' '.' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '.' '.']
#  ['.' '.' '.' '0' '0' '0' '.' '.' '.']
#  ['.' '.' '.' '.' '0' '.' '.' '.' '.']]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easier to do this with a one dimensional array than it is with a 2D array (edit: I was wrong, the [`zip` approach is pretty darn easy too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34347121/364696), and the best IMO; leaving this for comparison), so just for fun, we'll convert to 1D, than rotate to a new 2D:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> # Collapses to 1D
>>> grid1d = list(chain(*grid))
>>> # Rotates and rebuilds as 2D
>>> numcolumns = len(grid[0])
>>> rotated = [grid1d[i::numcolumns] for i in range(numcolumns)]
>>> print(*rotated, sep="\n")
['.', '.', '0', '0', '.', '0', '0', '.', '.']
['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.']
['.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.']
['.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '0', '0', '0', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '0', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

Side-note: If you're on Python 2, that `print` syntax would require a `from __future__ import print_function` to work.