# Fastest way to iterate over a large list containing strings in Python?

Tags: python, database, list, loops, iteration

I have a large list that contains 30000 other lists. The large list contains a list of a string and two other lists. Here is an example:

```
large_list = [
    ...
    ['maj', [4, 7], ['3', '5']],
    ['maj7', [4, 7, 11], ['3', '5', '7']],
    ...
    ]
```

I want to iterate through this large_list and find the smaller list by looking for the name (maj, maj7, etc.).

What is the fastest way of doing this?

I had thought to put the list in a .txt file and reading line by line, but I don't really know if that's faster. All I know is it takes less of a toll on my IDE, as having a list of 30000 lines makes any coding sluggish.

Comment: where are the 3000000 lines coming from? how do they get into python?

Comment: see if this helps--> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10929724/11669010)

Comment: you might want to look at the solution implemented here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923218/12337794

Comment: Would it be more efficient to declare/convert your structure as/to a dictionary, so you can do `large_dict['maj7']` to do the lookup. BTW, your syntax looks wrong - should there be a close square bracket at the end of the two sample lines?

Comment: The lines came from other code that generated the correct attributes @Joran

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas
# convert it to a dataframe
df = pandas.DataFrame(largeList)
#select all the rows where the zeroth element starts with "maj"
mask = df[0].str.startswith("maj")
print(df[mask])
```

Comment: I hadn't heard of DataFrame, but this looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Bud,**

I am pretty new to Python, however, in this case, my best guess to find the smallest of them all sublist in this gigantic monster called large_list is by using the code shared below:

```
large_list=[['maj', 4, 7], ['3', '5'], ['maj9', 7], ['maj3', 100], ['maj4', 1360], ['maj7', 4, 7, 11], ['3', '5', '7']]
def getTheMinGuy(mylist):
    minimum = min(mylist)
    return print(f"The smaller sublist on this list is => {minimum}")
getTheMinGuy(large_list)
```

I certainly hope this helps finding the best solution for this issue, champion. Cheers!

Comment: how does this help him solve the problem? i dont think this code will do what you think it will do... he wants a sublist containing all the elements that start with maj or some variant of maj