# Loop through 2D array in reverse

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to go through a 2D array in reverse. Thats is why I use [reversed()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0322/) but I get an error that says

> list indices must be integers, not list

Array example:

```
labirynth = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]
```

My current solution:

```
for i in reversed(labirynth):
    for j in reversed(labirynth[i]):
        #do stuff
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotating a two-dimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421337/rotating-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to access the list with `[]`. The outer for loop already returns the list. You can just do

```
for i in reversed(labirynth):
    for j in reversed(i):
        # do stuf...
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
for i in reversed(labirynth):
  for j in reversed(i):
    # do stuff
```

here's an interactive demo:

```
>>> labirynth = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
[1,0,1,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]
... ... ... ... ...
>>> for i in reversed(labirynth):
...    print i
... 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> for i in reversed(labirynth):
...   for j in reversed(i):
...     print j
... 
1
1
1
... continues
```

Comment: That precisely solves my problem. Thank you for such good explanation!