# How do I initialize a column vector of a 2D list/array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, python-3.x, matrix

Suppose I have a list of list called `mat` of shape `5x5`.

Then I initialize a "column", element by element as follows

```
mat[0][4] = 'X'
mat[1][4] = 'O'
mat[2][4] = 'R'
mat[3][4] = 'N'
mat[4][4] = 'A'
```

Is there any way to initialize this column vector in one line in `Python` like how `MATLAB` might do?

```
mat[:,4] = ['X','O','R','N','A']
```

Comment: Be careful of confusing a list of lists in python with a matlab 2D matrix. If you want a more direct map to matlab, check `numpy`. Although there I'd advise against using characters as elements.

Comment: I would guess that this is used for some sort of traditional cipher, where a 5*5 grid of letters is common (the English alphabet has 26 letters, and an uncommon letter can be dropped/replaced according to some rule).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite as concise, but:

```
for i,x in enumerate(['X','O','R','N','A']): mat[i][4]=x
```

Or in the case of single characters, slightly shorter:

```
for i,x in enumerate('XORNA'): mat[i][4]=x
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `numpy`:

```
import numpy
mat=numpy.array([[' ' for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)])
mat[:,4] = ['X','O','R','N','A']
```

Comment: I'd change the creation of the matrix as `mat = numpy.empty((5,5), dtype=object)`. Seems clearer that a double list comprehension. Didn't want to edit myself, as the code is not wrong ;)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem a couple of years ago while developing a Sudoku algorithm. I had to frequently switch between columns and rows and the nested "for" where killing me.

So I came up with the easy solution to just rotate my matrix and always treat everything as a row. If optimisation is not an issue, you can do that.

Here is how to rotate a multi-dimensional array in python: [Rotating a two-dimensional array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421337/rotating-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

Comment: Transposing instead of rotating would be conceptually more clear (and less code). But yes, this works too.