# How to rotate a matrix to 90 degrees?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array)

Beginner in C++ , Need to rotate to 90 degrees, I already tried to do with the help of others posts here , but without luck. Sorry for English

```
 # define D 9

int Ta [D][D];
short i, j;
short c=1;

for ( i=0; i < D ; i++)  {
    for ( j = 0 ;  j < D; j++)


    if ((j>i) && (j<D-i-1))  Ta[i][j]=c++; 
    else if((j>D-i-1) && (j<i)) Ta[i][j]=c++;
        else Ta[i][j]=0;  

}

for ( i = 0; i < D; i++) {
    for ( j= 0; j < D; j++) {
        printf("%3d",Ta[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What's going wrong? What did you dig up during debugging?

Comment: How many dimensions, and about which axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer was : Thanks to Adam Liss

```
int r[D][D];

for (i=0; i<D; ++i) {
    for (j=0; j<D; ++j) {
        r[i][j] = t[D-j-1][i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note that this puts some strain on memory, for large arrays. Use with caution.