# How do we rotate a tetris piece counter clockwise?

Tags: java, matrix, rotation

I looked at the algorithm here for clockwise rotation, but I can't do it the other way around. So basically, for clockwise rotation, you need to multiply the transpose to a rotation matrix, but how do you do the same thing the other way around?

Here's my code:

```
public class rotation2 {

    public static int [][] multiplyMatrix(int [][] m1) {
        int [][] m2 = {{0,0,0,1},
                       {0,0,1,0},
                       {0,1,0,0},
                       {1,0,0,0}};
        int[][] result = new int[4][4];

        // multiply
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
                for (int k=0; k<4; k++)
                    result[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];

        return result;
    }

    public static int [][] multiplyMatrix2(int [][] m2) {
        int [][] m1 = {{0,0,0,1},
                       {0,0,1,0},
                       {0,-1,0,0},
                       {-1,0,0,0}};
        int[][] result = new int[4][4];

        // multiply
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++)
                for (int k=0; k<4; k++)
                    result[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];

        return result;
    }

    public static void printArray(int [][] array) {
        for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for(int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
                if (array[row][col] > 0) {
                    System.out.printf("1");
                } else {
                    System.out.printf("0");
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
    }

    public static int [][] transpose(int [][] m1) {
        int m = 4;
        int n = 4;
        int c = 0;
        int d = 0;

        int[][] transpose = new int [n][m];

        for ( c = 0 ; c < m ; c++ ) {
            for ( d = 0 ; d < n ; d++ ) {
                transpose[d][c] = m1[c][d];
            }
        }
        return transpose;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] m1 = {{1,0,0,0},
                       {1,0,0,0},
                       {1,1,0,0},
                       {0,0,0,0}};

        int [][] transpose = transpose(m1);
        printArray(transpose);
        transpose = multiplyMatrix(transpose);
        printArray(transpose);

        int [][] transpose2 = transpose(m1);
        printArray(transpose2);
        transpose2 = multiplyMatrix(transpose2);
        printArray(transpose2);
    }
}
```

You don't transpose for counter clock rotation, right?

Comment: See also this previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14867570/230513).

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to (1) transpose the matrix, and (2) inverse the rows (clockwise) or columns (counter-clockwise), respectively.

You can just use a double-for-loop to set the new values for the individual cells, doing both steps at the same time. In code, this might look like this:

```
public static int[][] rotate(int[][] m, boolean left) {
    int rows = m.length, cols = m[0].length;
    int[][] m2 = new int[cols][rows]; // swap rows and cols
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            if (left) // rotate left
                m2[c][r] = m[r][cols - c - 1];
            else      // rotate right
                m2[c][r] = m[rows - r - 1][c];
    return m2;
}
```

For more information and alternative approaches, take a look at the answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array).