# How to rotate a matrix in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, matrix

(disclosure, I'm mostly math illiterate).

I have an array in this format:

```
var grid = [
  [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3],
  [1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [1,3],
  [2,0], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3],
  [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3]
];
```

I need to "rotate" it by 90deg increments, so it's like this:

```
var grid = [
  [3,0], [2,0], [1,0], [0,0], 
  [3,1], [2,1], [1,1], [0,1], 
  [3,2], [2,2], [1,2], [0,2], 
  [3,3], [2,3], [1,3], [0,3] 
];
```

How do I accomplish this in Javascript?

Comment: are you trying to do this specifically for a 4x4 matrix, or for any matrix of arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: @Blender: I've tried `grid.map(function(d,i){return [Math.abs(d[1]-3), d[0]]})` which does it for one increment but it's obviously wrong from a math standpoint.

Comment: @ultranaut I need it for arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: is there a mistake in output grid last row ? it should be
var grid = [
  [3,0], [2,0], [1,0], [0,0],
  [3,1], [2,1], [1,1], [0,1],
  [3,2], [2,2], [1,2], [0,2],
  [3,3], [2,3], [1,3], [0,3]
]; .right ?

Comment: @rab ahhhh yes you're right. Updated question.

Comment: Then I'd think you'd want to set it up as something like `var grid = [[[0,0], [0,1]],[[1,0], [1,1]]]` so that your code has some way to know what the dimensions are, no?

Comment: @ultranaut ah, but the grid will always be squared.

Comment: @Duopixel got it, not completely arbitrary but square

Comment: @methodofaction I know it is a very old question. But I found this really nice explanation in this article. https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/matrix-rotation-%EF%B8%8F-6550397f16ab

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Rotating a two dimensional m x n matrix

Those looking for Rotating a two dimensional matrix (a more general case) here is how to do it.

example:
Original Matrix:

```
[
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6], 
  [7,8,9]
]
```

Rotated at 90 degrees:

```
[
    [7,4,1]
    [8,5,2]
    [9,6,3]
]
```

This is done in following way:

```
matrix[0].map((val, index) => matrix.map(row => row[index]).reverse())
```

For counter-clockwise rotation (Thanks to @karn-ratana):

```
matrix[0].map((val, index) => matrix.map(row => row[row.length-1-index]));
```

Comment: This approach can only be applied to a square matrix.

Comment: @PreethamSridhar Over the top of my head, I think this approach is applicable to non-square matrices as well, it has nothing to do with matrix being square.

Comment: For counter-clockwise:

```matrix[0].map((val, index) => matrix.map(row => row[row.length-1-index]));
```

Comment: Thanks @KarnRatana, added this to answer! cheers.

Comment: It's super!; and contrary to what **Preetham Sridhar** says, it also works for rectangular shapes. FYI, I use this algorithm for rotations (of words or blocks) to arange crossword puzzles.

Comment: Someone might want to add 180 for completeness.

Answer (score 19):

Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array) for the actual rotation method.

My method was pretty straightforward. Just determine what the row length was, and then iterate through each item, converting the array index to x/y equivalents and then apply the method used in the linked answer to rotate.  Finally I converted the rotated X/Y coordinates back to an array index.

```
var grid = [
  [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3],
  [1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [1,3],
  [2,0], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3],
  [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3]
]; 

var newGrid = [];
var rowLength = Math.sqrt(grid.length);
newGrid.length = grid.length

for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
{
    //convert to x/y
    var x = i % rowLength;
    var y = Math.floor(i / rowLength);

    //find new x/y
    var newX = rowLength - y - 1;
    var newY = x;

    //convert back to index
    var newPosition = newY * rowLength + newX;
    newGrid[newPosition] = grid[i];
}

for (var i = 0; i < newGrid.length; i++)
{   
    console.log(newGrid[i])
}
```

The output:

```
[3, 0] [2, 0] [1, 0] [0, 0]  
[3, 1] [2, 1] [1, 1] [0, 1]  
[3, 2] [2, 2] [1, 2] [0, 2]  
[3, 3] [2, 3] [1, 3] [0, 3]
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbC7H/3/) for the lazy. And a [5x5 grid fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbC7H/7/) to demonstrate that the algorithm works for N grid sizes as long as they are square.

Comment: That's such a beautiful solution, clean and minimal. (has to be a square matrix though)

Comment: "has to be a square matrix though" is a problem to me... if i want to rotate a 2x8 matrix, how would you do?

Answer (score 11):

These are two function for clockwise and counterclockwise 90-degree rotation:

```
    function rotateCounterClockwise(a){
        var n=a.length;
        for (var i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
            for (var j=i; j<n-i-1; j++) {
                var tmp=a[i][j];
                a[i][j]=a[j][n-i-1];
                a[j][n-i-1]=a[n-i-1][n-j-1];
                a[n-i-1][n-j-1]=a[n-j-1][i];
                a[n-j-1][i]=tmp;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    function rotateClockwise(a) {
        var n=a.length;
        for (var i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
            for (var j=i; j<n-i-1; j++) {
                var tmp=a[i][j];
                a[i][j]=a[n-j-1][i];
                a[n-j-1][i]=a[n-i-1][n-j-1];
                a[n-i-1][n-j-1]=a[j][n-i-1];
                a[j][n-i-1]=tmp;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really need to deal with indices, since I can copy the values from one place to the other, this simplifies the answer a bit:

```
var grid = [
  [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4],
  [1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4],
  [2,0], [2,1], [2,2], [2,3], [2,4],
  [3,0], [3,1], [3,2], [3,3], [3,4],
  [4,0], [4,1], [4,2], [4,3], [4,4]
]; 

var side = Math.sqrt(grid.length);

var rotate = function(d,i){
   return [Math.abs(i % side - side+1), Math.floor(i/side)]
}
grid = grid.map(rotate);
```

You can see a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KmtPg/

Comment: When I change any values in your initial grid with this solution the output doesn't change, do you really not want the input to matter?

Comment: Yes, those are just coordinates of a grid, but your answer is much more relevant most of the time so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work with any kind of matrix but if it's not n*n and the size is n*m it will have undefined items in the array (I set it to return null in case of undefined), but it works at the end and you will have a rotated array.

```
//ES6 function
const rotateMatrix = (matrix) => {
let temp;
for (let i = 1; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix.length / 2; j++) {
        temp = matrix[i][j];
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i] === undefined ? null : matrix[j][i];
        matrix[j][i] = temp;
    }
}
return matrix;
};

// 3,3 matrix example
console.table(rotateMatrix([[1, 2, 64], [4, 5, 55], [7, 8, 34]]));
// 5*3 matrix example
console.table(rotateMatrix([[1, 2, 64], [4, 5, 55], [7, 8, 34], [10, 15, 65], [22, 24, 56]]));
```