# find transposed matrix using lodash

Tags: javascript, algorithm, transpose, lodash

I have an array:

> [
>      [1,2,3],
>      [4,5,6]
>   ]

How can I turn it into

> [
>      [1,4],
>      [2,5],
>      [3,6]
>   ]

I am sure it's something I can do easily with lodash but I have not found it in the docs.

Comment: You're looking for `_.zip()`

Comment: @Pointy, but zip() is only in python , right ?

Comment: @vtz ?? No, [it's also part of Lodash.](https://lodash.com/docs#zip)

Comment: Seen this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17428779/2059482

Comment: ah yes, never heard of it, tnx @Pointy

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. why is that necessary? Is it generalized to higher-dimension arrays?

Comment: @Pointy you are right .... deleting comment

Comment: @Pointy the solution in [link](https://github.com/jlmorgan/lodash-transpose/blob/master/src/transpose.js)  I do not feel bad solution

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. I don't think it's bad either; I was just curious as to what it does that `_.zip()` doesn't do. I suppose I could just read the code :)

Answer (score 9):

a solution using lodash

```
m = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ];
t = _.zip.apply(_, m);
// result t = [ [1,4], [2,5], [3,6] ]
m = [ [1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3,3] ]
t = _.zip.apply(_, m);
// result t = [ [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3] ]
```

explanation:

apply: Make the call to a function with a given value for this and   arguments passed as an array ..... is same that _.zip(arg0, arg1, arg2) similar _.zip.apply(null, m) where m = [arg0, arg1, arg2]

Comment: You can just `_.zip(...m)`

Answer (score 0):

`_.zip(['fred', 'barney'], [30, 40], [true, false]);
// → [['fred', 30, true], ['barney', 40, false]]
// Official documentation`

Official documentation.
https://lodash.com/docs#zip

Comment: OP want to use lodash library, he want not tranpose matrix algorithm

Comment: Duh! Sorry I didn't read **lodash** in the description. ;S

Comment: I changed the answer @JoseRicardoBustosM. :)