# Kendo grid side header?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there any way that I can have my kendo grid header in the side of the table instead of being on top of the grid?

In a normal table I would just put the headers where I want but since kendo is rendering the table for me how can I do this?

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862133/how-to-transpose-rows-and-columns-in-a-kendo-ui-grid-in-mvc-application

Comment: will look into, thanks @MantasČekanauskas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpose rows and columns in a Kendo UI grid in MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862133/how-to-transpose-rows-and-columns-in-a-kendo-ui-grid-in-mvc-application)