# Sort other arrays by order of specific array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, rowsorter

I have a bunch of arrays in this form:

```
var myRows = [
    [{idx: 0, val: 90}, {idx: 1, val: 75}, {idx: 2, val: 35}],
    [{idx: 0, val: 50}, {idx: 1, val: 17}, {idx: 2, val: 95}],
    [{idx: 0, val: 10}, {idx: 1, val: 24}, {idx: 2, val: 80}]
  // ...
];
```

Lets say I would like to sort the first row ascending by `val`, so it becomes:

```
[{idx: 2, val: 35}, {idx: 1, val: 75}, {idx: 0, val: 90}]
```

Is there an easy way to sort the remaining arrays, so that their order matches the `idx`-order of the sorted first row?

```
myArrays = [
    [{idx: 2, val: 35}, {idx: 1, val: 75}, {idx: 0, val: 90}]
  , [{idx: 2, val: 95}, {idx: 1, val: 17}, {idx: 0, val: 50}]
  , [{idx: 2, val: 80}, {idx: 1, val: 24}, {idx: 0, val: 10}]
  // ...
];
```

Maybe this is even possible without the `idx` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map) and apply the mapping for all items.

This proposal saves the indices, order the array and applies the order to all other arrays as well.

```js
// the array to be sorted
var list = [[{ idx: 0, val: 90 }, { idx: 1, val: 75 }, { idx: 2, val: 35 }], [{ idx: 0, val: 50 }, { idx: 1, val: 17 }, { idx: 2, val: 95 }], [{ idx: 0, val: 10 }, { idx: 1, val: 24 }, { idx: 2, val: 80 }]];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = list[0].map(function (el, i) {
    return { index: i, value: el.val };
})

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
});

// rearrange all items in list
list.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    aa[i] = mapped.map(function (el) {
        return a[el.index];
    });
});

console.log(list);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you drop the idx property, you can just use an array:

```js
// Function copied from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36164530/5710637
var transpose = m => m[0].map((x,i) => m.map(x => x[i]))

var sortByRow = 0    
var myRows = [
  [90, 75, 35],
  [50, 17, 95],
  [10, 24, 80]
]
var myCols = transpose(myRows)
myCols.sort((x, y) => x[sortByRow] - y[sortByRow])
myRows = transpose(myCols)
console.log(myRows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

```
var order = myRows[0].map(function(e) { return e.idx })
myRows.forEach(function(row) { 
    row.sort(function(a,b) { 
        return order.indexOf(a.idx) - order.indexOf(b.idx);
    });
});
```

This is very simple code just to demonstate the idea.
It will probably be slow for very large arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following which does,

- Sort the first row of array<sup>1</sup>, and store their `idx`es in a temporary array<sup>2</sup>
- Assign the remaining array with a `temp` property according to the first `idx`<sup>3</sup>
- Sort the remaining array based on their `temp` property<sup>4</sup> (Which is based on the first array)
- Remove the `temp` property<sup>5</sup>

**E.g.**

```js
var filteredRows = [];
var myRows = [
    [{idx: 0, val: 90}, {idx: 1, val: 75}, {idx: 2, val: 35}],
    [{idx: 0, val: 50}, {idx: 1, val: 17}, {idx: 2, val: 95}],
    [{idx: 0, val: 10}, {idx: 1, val: 24}, {idx: 2, val: 80}]
];

/* 1. Sort the first row */
myRows[0].sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.val - b.val;
});
filteredRows.push(myRows[0]);

/* 2. Get indexes */
var idxs = [];
for (var obj of myRows[0]) {
    idxs.push(obj.idx);
}

/* Handle the remaining array */
myRows.slice(1).map(function (val) {
    /* 3. Assign temp value */
    val.map(function (obj, i) {
        obj.temp = idxs[i];
    });

    /* 4. Sort them */
    val.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.temp - b.temp;
    });

    /* 5. Remove temp value */
    val.map(function (obj, i) {
        delete obj.temp;
    });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(myRows));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `hash table` to create a sorting criteria based on the first row - see demo below:

```js
var myRows=[[{idx:0,val:90},{idx:1,val:75},{idx:2,val:35}],[{idx:0,val:50},{idx:1,val:17},{idx:2,val:95}],[{idx:0,val:10},{idx:1,val:24},{idx:2,val:80}]];

// sort the first row (as desired)
myRows[0].sort((a,b) => a.val - b.val);

myRows.forEach(function(c,i){
    if(i === 0){
      // create order criteria based on first row
      c.forEach(function(e, k){
        this[e.idx] = k;
      });
    } else {
      c.sort(function(a,b) {
        return this[a.idx] - this[b.idx];
      });
    }
 }, Object.create(null));
      
console.log(myRows);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```