# Converting an object of arrays into array of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
object = {
          'AAA' : [1, 2, 3],
          'BBB' : [4, 5, 6]
      }
```

I have an object that looks like this but I need to convert it into an array of array that looks like:

```
arr = [['AAA', 'BBB'],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]]
```

To be pass-able to the excel library that I am using.

What is a good way to convert the format like that in Javascript?

Comment: Make an effort of your own for starters ... [ask]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript for how to transpose a 2D array. It should be pretty simple to adapt the solutions to an object containing arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the keys of the object and then take a nested approach for the outer iteration of the keys and for the inner iteration of the values.

Then assign a new array, if not given and take the index of the outer array for assigning the value. Later concat the result with the keys as first array.

```js
var object = { AAA : [1, 2, 3], BBB : [4, 5, 6, 8] },
    keys = Object.keys(object),
    array = [keys].concat(keys.reduce((r, k, j) => {
        object[k].forEach((v, i) => (r[i] = r[i] || [])[j] = v);
        return r;
    }, []));
    
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what if I set one more item for `BBB`? Right now it seems like an additional `8` in `BBB` will append to the first element of the fourth array.

Comment: i changed to assigning at an index instead of pushing the value. you might get sparse arrays who do not have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for given scenario:**

```js
const objj = {
  'AAA' : [1, 2, 3],
  'BBB' : [4, 5, 6]
}

const getFormattedArray = (objJ) => {
  const formatted = []
  const keys = Object.keys(objJ)
  const values = Object.values(objJ)
  const [val1, val2] = [...values]
  formatted.push(keys)
  getFormattedChild(val1, val2).forEach(item => {
    formatted.push(item)
  })
  return formatted
}

const getFormattedChild = (a, b) => {
  let blob = []
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    let derp = []
    derp.push(a[i])
    derp.push(b[i])
    blob.push(derp)
  }
  return blob
}

const result = getFormattedArray(objj)
console.log('result: \n', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution, If `AAA` and `BBB` have different array values:**

```js
const objj = {
  'AAA' : [1, 2, 3, null],
  'BBB' : [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}

const getFormattedArray = (objJ) => {
  const formatted = []
  const keys = Object.keys(objJ)
  const values = Object.values(objJ)
  const [val1, val2] = [...values]
  formatted.push(keys)
  getFormattedChild(val1, val2).forEach(item => {
    formatted.push(item)
  })
  return formatted
}

const getFormattedChild = (a, b) => {
  let blob = []
  const aLength = a.length
  const bLength = b.length
  const upperLimit = (aLength <= bLength) ? bLength : aLength
  for (let i = 0; i < upperLimit; i++){
    let derp = []
    derp.push(a[i])
    derp.push(b[i])
    blob.push(derp)
  }
  return blob
}

const result = getFormattedArray(objj)
console.log('result: \n', result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to do it succinctly in one line, based on a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript/17428705#17428705):

```
const arr = [Object.keys(object), Object.values(object)[0].map((col, i) => Object.values(object).map(row => row[i]))];
```

```js
var object = {
          'AAA' : [1, 2, 3],
          'BBB' : [4, 5, 6]
      };
      
const arr = [Object.keys(object), Object.values(object)[0].map((col, i) => Object.values(object).map(row => row[i]))];

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var obj = {
          'AAA' : [1, 2, 3],
          'BBB' : [4, 5, 6]
      };

const result = [Object.keys(obj)];
result.concat(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].reduce((acc, ele, i)=>{
  acc.push([ele,obj[Object.keys(obj)[1]][i]]);
  return acc;
},[]));
```

Output:

```
[ [ 'AAA', 'BBB' ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ], [ 3, 6 ] ]
```