# Sudoku JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sudoku

I had an interview. I had to code live. I couldn't solve the question here is the question

- you have two sets of nested array and these are the rules

  - Each row must contain the numbers 1 through 9 with no repetitions.
  - Each column must contain the numbers 1 through 9 with no repetitions.
  - Each 3x3 block must contain the numbers 1 through 9 with no repetitions.

I tried the first bit but I don't know how to add missing number also I have no clue for the rest

---

"use strict";

```
const invalidBoard = [
  [ 5, 3, 4,  6, 7, 9,  8, 1, 2 ],
  [ 6, 7, 2,  1, 9, 5,  3, 4, 7 ], 
  [ 6, 9, 8,  3, 4, 2,  7, 6, 5 ],

  [ 8, 5, 9,  7, 6, 1,  4, 2, 1 ],
  [ 4, 2, 6,  8, 5, 3,  7, 8, 1 ],
  [ 7, 1, 3,  9, 2, 4,  8, 5, 6 ],

  [ 9, 6, 1,  5, 3, 7,  2, 8, 4 ],
  [ 2, 8, 7,  4, 1, 9,  6, 3, 5 ],
  [ 3, 4, 5,  2, 8, 6,  1, 8, 8 ],
];

const validBoard = [
  [ 5, 3, 4,  6, 7, 8,  9, 1, 2 ],
  [ 6, 7, 2,  1, 9, 5,  3, 4, 8 ],
  [ 1, 9, 8,  3, 4, 2,  5, 6, 7 ],

  [ 8, 5, 9,  7, 6, 1,  4, 2, 3 ],
  [ 4, 2, 6,  8, 5, 3,  7, 9, 1 ],
  [ 7, 1, 3,  9, 2, 4,  8, 5, 6 ],

  [ 9, 6, 1,  5, 3, 7,  2, 8, 4 ],
  [ 2, 8, 7,  4, 1, 9,  6, 3, 5 ],
  [ 3, 4, 5,  2, 8, 6,  1, 7, 9 ],
];

console.log("Invalid board is invalid: " + !isValid(invalidBoard));
console.log("Valid board is valid: " + isValid(validBoard));

function isValid(board) {
 //this is what I wrote
 for(i=0; i<invalidBoard.length; i++){
let value = invalidBoard[i];
 const result= value.filter(item=>item<10)
 const sort= result.sort()

 const uniq=[... new Set(sort)]
 console.log(uniq)


 }
}
```

Comment: This was an interview question? It's non-trival and I'd hate to see it in an interview. I suppose it could be measuring what approach you'd take without expecting you'd solve it...but I think it's still bad.

Comment: I don't get what is the question. You were supposed to code a validator?

Comment: Wait, I realised, they've lifted this wholesale from [CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/529bf0e9bdf7657179000008)! The example boards are *exactly* the same.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my approach, at first check all rows, then rearrange the cols to rows and validate it with the rows validator and the do the same for the blocks.

```
const invalidBoard = [
    [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 8, 1, 2],
    [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 7],
    [6, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 7, 6, 5],

    [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 1],
    [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 8, 1],
    [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],

    [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
    [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
    [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 8, 8]
];

const validBoard = [
    [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
    [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
    [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],

    [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
    [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
    [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],

    [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
    [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
    [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]
];

function validateRows(arr) {
    let isValid = true;
    arr.forEach(row => {
        let rowCopy = [...row];
        rowCopy.sort();
        rowCopy.forEach((number, index) => {
            if (number !== index + 1) {
                isValid = false;
            }
        });
    });

    return isValid;
}

function colsToRows(arr) {
    let ret = [];

    arr.forEach(row => {
        row.forEach((number, index) => {
            if (!Array.isArray(ret[index])) {
                ret[index] = [];
            }
            ret[index].push(number);
        });
    });

    return ret;
}

function blocksToRows(arr) {
    let blocks = [];
    let ret = [];

    for (let h = 0; h < 3; h++) {
        arr.forEach(row => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                blocks.push(row.shift());
            }
        });
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
            if (!Array.isArray(ret[j])) {
                ret[j] = [];
            }
            ret[j].push(blocks.shift());
        }
    }

    return ret;
}


console.log(validateRows(invalidBoard));
console.log(validateRows(colsToRows(invalidBoard)));
console.log(validateRows(blocksToRows(invalidBoard)));

console.log(validateRows(validBoard));
console.log(validateRows(colsToRows(validBoard)));
console.log(validateRows(blocksToRows(validBoard)));
```

Output:

```
false
false
false
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for validating X and Y 'axis.
Quite a fun exercise, Checking the squared groups will take abit more time which i will try later.

```js
const invalidBoard = [
  [ 5, 3, 4,  6, 7, 9,  8, 1, 2 ],
  [ 6, 7, 2,  1, 9, 5,  3, 4, 7 ], 
  [ 6, 9, 8,  3, 4, 2,  7, 6, 5 ],

  [ 8, 5, 9,  7, 6, 1,  4, 2, 1 ],
  [ 4, 2, 6,  8, 5, 3,  7, 8, 1 ],
  [ 7, 1, 3,  9, 2, 4,  8, 5, 6 ],

  [ 9, 6, 1,  5, 3, 7,  2, 8, 4 ],
  [ 2, 8, 7,  4, 1, 9,  6, 3, 5 ],
  [ 3, 4, 5,  2, 8, 6,  1, 8, 8 ],
];

const validBoard = [
  [ 5, 3, 4,  6, 7, 8,  9, 1, 2 ],
  [ 6, 7, 2,  1, 9, 5,  3, 4, 8 ],
  [ 1, 9, 8,  3, 4, 2,  5, 6, 7 ],

  [ 8, 5, 9,  7, 6, 1,  4, 2, 3 ],
  [ 4, 2, 6,  8, 5, 3,  7, 9, 1 ],
  [ 7, 1, 3,  9, 2, 4,  8, 5, 6 ],

  [ 9, 6, 1,  5, 3, 7,  2, 8, 4 ],
  [ 2, 8, 7,  4, 1, 9,  6, 3, 5 ],
  [ 3, 4, 5,  2, 8, 6,  1, 7, 9 ],
];

const validate_axis = data => {
  const _S = new Set(data)
  return [..._S].length === data.length
}

const validate = board => {
  const X_VALID = board.every(validate_axis)
  const Y_VALID = (
    board
    .map((_, i) => board.map(r => r[i]))
    .every(validate_axis)
  )
   
  return X_VALID && Y_VALID
}

const invalid = validate(invalidBoard)
const valid = validate(validBoard)

console.log(invalid)
console.log(valid)
```

Comment: This is brilliant in my opinion. I notice that you don't check if two numbers are in the same square, but I think it's intended since if two numbers are in the same square, it means that there are also two numbers in the same row or column

Comment: @CristianTraìna I thought maybe a two number check would be irrelevant if i compared the original array (axis) with the axis placed into a `Set` which does not allow duplicates. so any array (with duplicates) that is placed into a set would actually have a shorter length than the original array.

Comment: Yes I didn't mean this, I meant that you do this check on row and numbers, but not cells

Comment: I do still need to do the work towards 3X3 cells.

Comment: as I said, I don't know if it's needed

Comment: I think it is, if a duplicate was found diagonally within a 3X3 square.

Comment: Yes, it is needed, there is a certain sudoku board that can have all rows and all columns validated but no grid is a valid grid: that is where each row is shifted one number from the previous. The first column would look like `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and the fifth like `[5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down this to the smallest possible problem and build up

---

### Check if the content of each cell is correct

First of all, you want to check if the content of each cell is correct. To do that, you have to verify that the value of each cell is a number between `1` and `9`. This is simple enough

```js
function isCellContentValid(value) {
  return typeof value === "number"
    && value >= 1
    && value <= 9;
}

console.log("1   => ", isCellContentValid(1));
console.log("5   => ", isCellContentValid(5));
console.log("9   => ", isCellContentValid(9));
console.log("0   => ", isCellContentValid(0));
console.log("42  => ", isCellContentValid(42));
console.log("'a' => ", isCellContentValid('a'));
```

Since this code is pretty simple, we can quickly verify it's correct and using [`Array#every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) we can just check an entire row and we can be sure that the row is correct, since `.every()` will check if each cell conforms to the predicate:

```js
function isCellContentValid(value) {
  return typeof value === "number"
    && value >= 1
    && value <= 9;
}

function isRowContentValid(row) {
  return row.every(isCellContentValid);
}

console.log(isRowContentValid([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
console.log(isRowContentValid(['a', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

From there, we can trivially check if the entire board has valid content in its cells by using the same idea as above - use `.every()` to verify each row:

```js
function isBoardContentValid(board) {
  return board.every(isRowContentValid);
}
```

---

### Check if each row contains unique values

However, we also need to check if each collection of values contains unique values. It's easiest to start with rows, so let's do that.

There are many ways to check for uniqueness in an array but let's take one that is simple to read. Put the contents of the array in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which will only contain unique values. If the size of the set and the array are the same, that means that there were no duplicates. If there are any, then the set will not contain them and this have a different size:

```js
function isArrayUnique(array) {
  const set = new Set(array);
  return set.size === array.length;
}

console.log(isArrayUnique([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(isArrayUnique([1, 2, 2]));
```

This could be optimised but it works for illustrative purposes, since it's simple.

Once we can make sure an array is unique...we can just go through each row again and use `.every()` to verify that each row contains unique values:

```
function areRowsUnique(board) {
  return board.every(isArrayUnique);
}
```

---

### Check if each column contains unique values

Cool, one down - we checked the rows. Two to go. Let's go with columns next.

Columns are really just *rows* but positioned vertically. If you can treat them the same way, you can re-use the same logic. This is tricky but luckily, you *can* simplify it by doing a [matrix transposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript) which will essentially "rotate 90 degrees" the 2D array making a new one where the columns are now rows:

```js
function flipBoard(board) {
  //perform transposition
  return board[0].map((col, i) => board.map(row => row[i]));
}

//just to show off that it works
let exampleBoard = [
  ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
  ["a2", "b2", "c2"],
  ["a3", "b3", "c3"],
]

console.log(flipBoard(exampleBoard));

/* result:
[
  ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
  ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
  ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
]
*/
```

Thus the entire code needed to check if all columns contain correct values is to rotate the board and check every row (that was previously a column):

```js
function areColumnsUnique(board) {
  const flipped = flipBoard(board);
  return areRowsUnique(flipped);
}
```

---

### Check if each square contains unique values

All in all, the rows and columns were easy. They share most of the code, so it was a matter of finding how to link them. Where it becomes harder is the 3x3 squares. If we can extract each 3x3 square into a 9 element array, and collect each of those, we can re-use the previous logic again.

To do that, it's useful to think of the board in terms of sub-sections

```
║                       ║                       ║                       ║
║                       ║                       ║                       ║
║           A           ║           B           ║           C           ║
║                       ║                       ║                       ║
║                       ║                       ║                       ║
+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+===========
║ (0,0) | (1,0) | (2,0) ║ (3,0) | (4,0) | (5,0) ║ (6,0) | (7,0) | (8,0) ║
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
║ (0,1) | (1,1) | (2,1) ║ (3,1) | (4,1) | (5,1) ║ (6,1) | (7,1) | (8,1) ║      1
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
║ (0,2) | (1,2) | (2,2) ║ (3,2) | (4,2) | (5,2) ║ (6,2) | (7,2) | (8,2) ║
+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+===========
║ (0,3) | (1,3) | (2,3) ║ (3,3) | (4,3) | (5,3) ║ (6,3) | (7,3) | (8,3) ║
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
║ (0,4) | (1,4) | (2,4) ║ (3,4) | (4,4) | (5,4) ║ (6,4) | (7,4) | (8,4) ║      2
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
║ (0,5) | (1,5) | (2,5) ║ (3,5) | (4,5) | (5,5) ║ (6,5) | (7,5) | (8,5) ║
+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+===========
║ (0,6) | (1,6) | (2,6) ║ (3,6) | (4,6) | (5,6) ║ (6,6) | (7,6) | (8,6) ║
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
║ (0,7) | (1,7) | (2,7) ║ (3,7) | (4,7) | (5,7) ║ (6,7) | (7,7) | (8,7) ║      3
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
║ (0,8) | (1,8) | (2,8) ║ (3,8) | (4,8) | (5,8) ║ (6,8) | (7,8) | (8,8) ║
+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+=======+===========
```

This is a decent way to visualise it. The content of each cell specifies its coordinates and the double lines denote each of the 3x3 squares that need to be checked. So we need to extract each into an array To do so, we can employ some mathematics. But first, let's start with what we are trying to do - by examining the position of each cell we see that the top left with coordinates (0, 0) belongs to A1. However, (3, 3) belongs to B2, while (7, 6) in C3.

Since we want these extracted into one array each, let's re-label each square by just giving it a number

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   0   |   1   |   2   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   3   |   4   |   5   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   6   |   7   |   8   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

comparing the two representations that both show the squares, we can see that each coordinate falls into one of the numbered squares and we can determine which one by looking at the coordinates.

- (0, 0) => 0 (A1)
- (3, 3) => 4 (B1)
- (7, 6) => 8 (C3)

So even more general, we can derive the formula to find the index of the square a cell belongs to:`(rowIndex / 3) * 3 + (columnIndex / 3)`. We need to round down during division (in essence, performing integer division) in order to get an integer. We can plug our previous numbers in the formula we can verify it's correct:

- (0, 0) => (0 / 3) * 3 + (0 / 3) = 0 * 3 + 0 = 0 + 0 = 0 (A1)
- (3, 3) => (3 / 3) * 3 + (3 / 3) = 1 * 3 + 1 = 3 + 1 = 4 (B1)
- (7, 6) => (7 / 3) * 3 + (6 / 3) = 2 * 3 + 2 = 6 + 2 = 8 (C3)

With *all of this said*, we finally know what to do - we can walk the entire board and based on the coordinates of each cell, put it in an array that corresponds to its square. This leads us to the following code:

```js
function extractSquares(board) {
  //nine arrays for each square
  const squares = [
    [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
  ];
  
  board.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    row.forEach((cell, columnIndex) => {
      const squareIndex = (Math.floor(rowIndex / 3) * 3) + Math.floor(columnIndex / 3);

      squares[squareIndex].push(cell);
    })
  });

  return squares;
}
```

Thus we can finally define the last check:

```js
function areSquaresUnique(board) {
  const squares = extractSquares(board);
  return areRowsUnique(squares);
}
```

---

### Complete solution

Putting it all together, we get the following:

```js
function isValid(board){
  if (!isBoardContentValid(board)) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if (!areRowsUnique(board)) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if (!areColumnsUnique(board)) {
    return false;
  }
  
  if(!areSquaresUnique(board)) {
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}


function isCellContentValid(value) {
  return typeof value === "number" && value >= 1 && value <= 9;
}

function isBoardContentValid(board) {
  return board.every(isRowContentValid);
}

function isRowContentValid(row) {
  return row.every(isCellContentValid);
}

function isArrayUnique(array) {
  const set = new Set(array);
  return set.size === array.length;
}

function areRowsUnique(board) {
  return board.every(isArrayUnique);
}

function flipBoard(board) {
  return board[0].map((col, i) => board.map(row => row[i]))
}

function areColumnsUnique(board) {
  const flipped = flipBoard(board);
  return areRowsUnique(flipped);
}

function extractSquares(board) {
  //nine arrays for each square
  const squares = [
    [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
  ];

  board.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    row.forEach((cell, columnIndex) => {
      const squareIndex = (Math.floor(rowIndex / 3) * 3) + Math.floor(columnIndex / 3);

      squares[squareIndex].push(cell);
    })
  });

  return squares;
}

function areSquaresUnique(board) {
  const squares = extractSquares(board);
  return areRowsUnique(squares);
}

///////////////////////////////////

const invalidBoard = [
  [ 5, 3, 4,   6, 7, 9,   8, 1, 2 ],
  [ 6, 7, 2,   1, 9, 5,   3, 4, 7 ], 
  [ 6, 9, 8,   3, 4, 2,   7, 6, 5 ],

  [ 8, 5, 9,   7, 6, 1,   4, 2, 1 ],
  [ 4, 2, 6,   8, 5, 3,   7, 8, 1 ],
  [ 7, 1, 3,   9, 2, 4,   8, 5, 6 ],

  [ 9, 6, 1,   5, 3, 7,   2, 8, 4 ],
  [ 2, 8, 7,   4, 1, 9,   6, 3, 5 ],
  [ 3, 4, 5,   2, 8, 6,   1, 8, 8 ],
];

const validBoard = [
  [ 5, 3, 4,   6, 7, 8,   9, 1, 2 ],
  [ 6, 7, 2,   1, 9, 5,   3, 4, 8 ],
  [ 1, 9, 8,   3, 4, 2,   5, 6, 7 ],

  [ 8, 5, 9,   7, 6, 1,   4, 2, 3 ],
  [ 4, 2, 6,   8, 5, 3,   7, 9, 1 ],
  [ 7, 1, 3,   9, 2, 4,   8, 5, 6 ],

  [ 9, 6, 1,   5, 3, 7,   2, 8, 4 ],
  [ 2, 8, 7,   4, 1, 9,   6, 3, 5 ],
  [ 3, 4, 5,   2, 8, 6,   1, 7, 9 ],
];


console.log(isValid(validBoard)); // => true

console.log(isValid(invalidBoard)); // => false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little solution only for horizontal and vertical:

```
function isValidHorizontal(sudoku) {
    let numbersFind = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < sudoku.length; i++) {
        const arrayH = sudoku[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < arrayH.length; j++) {
            if (numbersFind.includes(arrayH[j])) {
                return false;
            } else {
                numbersFind.push(arrayH[j]);
            }
        }
        numbersFind.length = 0;
    }   

    return true;
}

function isValidVertical(sudoku) {
    let numbersFind = [];
    let pos = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < sudoku[0].length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < sudoku.length; j++) {
            if (numbersFind.includes(sudoku[j][pos])) {
                return false;
            } else {
                numbersFind.push(sudoku[j][pos]);
            }
        }
        numbersFind.length = 0;
        pos = 0;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think `reduce` would have been a better candidate than `for` loops. Also this is only the simplest part of the required solution, have you tried the vertical & groups parts ?

Comment: @Seblor a smart solution would re-use this but just re-define columns as "rows" and then the squares as "rows".

Comment: Yep, you are right @Seblor. The reduce it will be a better option. I coded quickly :P.
And yes, this code it could be re-defined for use one unique function for vertical and horizontal.