# JavaScript Transpose the Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am doing some work with data and I need a function that will transpose after data manipulation is finished. Right now the data looks like this.

```
var string ='"EMAIL","PHONE","ADDRESS","AREA"
"something@gmail.com","1 123 456","Some St. 1","700"
"something1@gmail.com","1 123 789","Some St. 2","800"
"something2@gmail.com","1 123 654","Some St. 3","900"
"something3@gmail.com","1 123 987","Some St. 4","1000" ';
```

I need a function that will convert these data into this:

```
var string = '"EMAIL","something@gmail.com","something1@gmail.com","something2@gmail.com","something3@gmail.com"
"PHONE","1 123 456","1 123 789","1 123 654","1 123 987"
"ADDRESS","Some St. 1","Some St. 2","Some St. 3","Some St. 4"
"AREA","700","800","900","1000"';
```

Comment: So you have that data as a string?

Comment: And what have you tried to solve that problem? What was your particular problem in getting that desired result? You need to show some [mvce] of what you have tried.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, rather a hint as to how I'd go about this: each line of your input is *almost* a [JSON array](https://www.json.org/), just without the `[` and `]` characters at either end. [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) will take care of the edge cases (like commas inside strings) for you. Then it's just a matter of [transposing the resulting array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17428587/1813169).

Comment: `var arr = JSON.parse("[["+str.replace(/\n/g,"],[")+"]]");`

Comment: @mplungjan "parse csv in js" yields a lot of results, most of them use some very complicated regexes / replacers. Your solution is quite elegant IMO ...

Comment: @JonasWilms yeah, I wanted to post a map/reduce but could not figure out an elegant enough map ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn that data as a string into a 2D array (or table, matrix, ...), then you can [transpose the matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript) and join it back to a string:

```
 const transpose = array => array[0].map((col, i) => array.map(row => row[i]));

  const result = transpose(
    data.split("\n").map(row => row.split(","))
  ).map(row => row.join(",")).join("\n");
```

Comment: This fails if one of the strings in the input contains a comma

Comment: I can manipulate text and replace comma with ; . So this could work.

Comment: Can you place this code in jsfiddle.net so I can see it work?

Comment: I choose this answer as best but I couldn't make it work on fiddle.