# Copy column A3:A9-E3:A9: to A,C,E,G, I in an other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Is it possible to copy from column A3:A9-E3:A9: and then target them to A,C,E,G,I in an other sheet?

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1znL2_1MniKdi2hqyYNbcF7VRCJ5NiwTzCUTcde_o7eI/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♦"&A3:E9&"♦");;999^99)); "♦"))
```

then copy with <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`C`**</kbd> and re-paste/paste over with <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd>+<kbd>**`V`**</kbd>

[image: 0]

Comment: Works perfectly as intended. I would never have guessed ♦ or ARRAYFORMULA combined with SPLIT and TRANSPOSE x 2 and a QUERY.

Comment: Just found out it doesn't work when i start to fill out B or D or F og H.

Comment: of course it doesn't work when you fill B, D, ... that's why I included CTRL+C > CTRL+SHIFT+V requirement in the answer

Comment: Sorry. Didn't mean to step toes here. I wanted it to be automatically done when a collegue updates a sheet. What I was trying to do was combining an week-sheet with  name-sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option, if you want to be able to use the columns in between, is using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). I don't think it is possible to do this with a sheets built-in function or even with an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions).

First, open a bound script by selecting `Tools > Script editor`, and copy the following function to the script:

```js
function copyRange() {
  // Retrieve original range:
  var inputRange = "'Ark1'!A3:E9"; // Range of original columns (please change this according to your preferences)
  var inputValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(inputRange).getValues();
  // Transpose array so that outer array corresponds to columns:
  var transposedValues = inputValues[0].map(function(column, i) {
    return inputValues.map(function(row) {
      return row[i];
    });
  });
  // Get selected range (this will be the destination range):
  var outputRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var targetSheet = outputRange.getSheet();
  var row = outputRange.getRow();
  var col = outputRange.getColumn();
  // Copy the source range to the destination (ignoring each second column):
  transposedValues.forEach(function(column, j) {
    for (var i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
      targetSheet.getRange(row + i, col + j * 2).setValue(column[i]);
    };
  });
}'
```

This script does the following:

- Retrieves the values in a certain range, **defined in the first line of this sample**, via [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) and [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- "Transposes" the retrieved 2D array corresponding to the values of the source range, so that each element in the outer array corresponds to a column, which will make the writing process easier, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17428705).
- Retrieve the currently selected range via [getActiveRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange())
- Copy the source range **to the currently selected range** with [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

The problem with this approach, of course, is that it's more uncomfortable to run this kind of functions than a built-in or a custom function. You could attach this function [to an image](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) or [to a menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) to make the workflow less painful. But I cannot think of a better solution.

Crucially, you would have to change the reference of the input range (in this sample `'Ark1'!A3:E9`).

#### Reference:

- [Sheet.getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange()))
- [Range.setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thank you for your extended effort and in depth explanation, but along the way I realized that I had been asking in the wrong question.