# How to work re-organize array so that its sorted in columns rather than rows

Tags: javascript

I have some checkboxes on a page that are organized in 3 columns. However they are alphabetically sorted and go across the rows instead.

What is currently happening:

```
A B C 
D E F
G H I
```

What I want to happen:

```
A D G
B E H
C F I
```

Right now I've got this code to work it out but I feel super confused by what to do when theres a remainder in the array and I don't know how to include it into the sorting without messing it up:

```
organizedCheckboxesArea() {

            let quotient = Math.floor(this.areas.length/3);
            let remainder = this.areas.length % 3;

            let organizedColumns = [];

            for(let i = 0 ; i < quotient; i++) {

                    organizedColumns.push(this.areas[i]);
                    organizedColumns.push(this.areas[quotient + i]);
                    organizedColumns.push(this.areas[(quotient * 2) + i]);
            }


            return organizedColumns;
        },
```

Its frustrating me a lot because I know the solution is simple I just can't think of it.

EDIT: this is not a 2 dimensional array. it is ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D' etc...].

Also for when there is a remainder, I want it to stack to the left two columms. ie ABCDEFGHIJ would make:

```
A E H
B F I
C G J
D
```

And ABCDEFGHIJK would make:

```
A E I
B F J
C G K
D H
```

Comment: Can you post ```this.areas``` array values??

Comment: _“what to do when theres a remainder in the array”_ - well start by explaining what you actually _want_ to do in that case? You only gave an example for the case where there isn’t any remainder - so what result you actually want in case there is, is not even clear right now.

Answer (score 1):

You could switch the indices and get a new array.

```js
var data = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'I']],
    result = data.reduce((r, a, j) => {
        a.forEach((v, i) => {
            r[i] = r[i] || [];
            r[i][j] = v;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Vanila JS: live code [here](https://runkit.com/embed/p3gxh0cet3nj)

```js
let A = [
 ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['D', 'E', 'F'],
 ['G', 'H', 'I'],
];

A[0].map((col, i) => A.map(row => row[i]));
A[0].map((_, i) => A.map(row => row[i])); // This also works
console.log(A);
```

using [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?let%20A%20%3D%20%5B%0A%09%5B%27A%27%2C%20%27B%27%2C%20%27C%27%5D%2C%0A%09%5B%27D%27%2C%20%27E%27%2C%20%27F%27%5D%2C%0A%09%5B%27G%27%2C%20%27H%27%2C%20%27I%27%5D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0AR.transpose%28A%29):

```
R.transpose(A);
```

using [lodash](https://jsfiddle.net/w8yuvgqn/):

```
_.zip.apply(_,A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Question answered here: [Transposing a 2D-array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript/17428705#17428705)

```
array[0].map((col, i) => array.map(row => row[i]));
```

> `map` calls a provided `callback` function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. `callback` is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.
>
> `callback` is invoked with three arguments: the value of the element, the index of the element, and the Array object being traversed. [[source]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)