# Rearrange values in an Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this data:

```
var ArrdeArr = [[1,2,3],[5,6,3],[9,5,1]]
var letter  = [x,y,z]
```

And each array in the ArrdeArr belongs to the letter.

**Expected Output:**

```
[x,[1,5,9]];
[y,[2,6,5]];
[z,[3,3,1]];
```

If I don't make myself clear please let me know

Comment: You need to [transpose the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript) to rearrange it in this way.

Comment: An what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my brain wasn't working. Here's what I came up with:

```js
function transpose(array){
  const r = array.map(()=>[]);
  array.forEach(a=>{
    a.forEach((n, i)=>{
      if(r[i])r[i].push(n);
    });
  });
  return r;
}
const trp = transpose([[1,2,3], [5,6,3], [9,5,1]]);
console.log(trp);
console.log({x:trp[0], y:trp[1], z:trp[2]});
```

Comment: LOL! It's ok... i have a question: What does transpose mean?
@StackSlave
You rock! btw, thanks

Comment: Transfer to somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

You may try it like this:

```js
var ArrdeArr = [[1,2,3],[5,6,3],[9,5,1]];
var letter  = ['x','y','z'];

const result = letter.map((e, i) => [e, ArrdeArr.map(_e => _e[i])]);

console.log(result);
```

The `x`, `y`, `z` doesn't exist in the context, so I replaced them with strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arrDeArr = [[1,2,3], [5,6,3], [9,5,1]]
const letter  = ['x', 'y', 'z']
const result = arrDeArr.reduce((a, c, i, arr) => [...a, [letter[i], arr.map(a => a[i])]], [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both the arrays are of same length

```
var ArrdeArr = [[1,2,3],[5,6,3],[9,5,1]]
  var letter = ["x", "y", "z"];
  var finalArray = []
  letter.map((letter, index) => {
    var nestedArr = [letter]
    ArrdeArr.map(element => {
      nestedArr.push(element[index])
    })
    finalArray.push(nestedArr)
  })

  console.log(finalArray)
```