# Take 3 variable length arrays and combine them into a arrays per index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting 3 arrays from an api response obj.  They can sometimes be empty or variable lengths.

Lets say I have these 3 arrays:

```
[]
["2a", "2b"]
["3a", "3b", "3c"]
```

I'd like to have the end result of combining these be a new array that contains 1 array per index:

```
[
  ["", "2a", "3a"],
  ["", "2b", "3b"],
  ["", "", "3c"]
]
```

Looking to see if someone has an "elegant" way to do this, as I can come up with a way to do this but it's rather grotesque.
Thanks

Comment: all you have to do  is const newArr = [ array1,array2,array3 ]

Comment: no special logic required.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier You are oversimplifying it because each of the input arrays  represents a column, not a row

Comment: aah i understand. you need it to be a table like structure

Comment: and you need the values assigned right to left

Answer (score 2):

Put the three responses into another array then use a nested `Array.from()` taking advantage of it's built in mapping function

```js
const ar = [
  [],
  ["2a", "2b"],
  ["3a", "3b", "3c"]
];

// get longest of either  subarray or main array lengths
const len = {length: Math.max(...[...ar.map(e => e.length), ar.length])};

const res = 
    Array.from(len, (_,i) => Array.from(len, (_,j) => (ar[j] && ar[j][i]) || ''))

console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

Comment: I have to admit, this is pretty slick and "Woah". Thanks.

Comment:  this is impressive

Comment: @Sheelpriy I realized that after and added a length object fix

Comment:   Now again impressive!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to take a 2D array and "rotate" it so the rows become columns. They are all then padded at the front to match the longest columns. This can be achieved in three steps:

1. Find the longest array. This is the target length.
2. Pad the start of each array with empty strings until it reaches the target length.
3. Perform [matrix transposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript) to "rotate" the array 90 degrees.

```js
//helper functions
function findLongest(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(
    (longest, currentArray) => Math.max(longest, currentArray.length),
    0
  )
}

function padStart(targetLength, fillWith, array) {
  const elementsNeeded = targetLength - array.length;
  const start = Array(elementsNeeded).fill(fillWith);
  
  return start.concat(array);
}

//from Fawad Ghafoor https://stackoverflow.com/a/17428705/
function transpose(array) {
  return array[0].map((_, colIndex) => array.map(row => row[colIndex]));
}

//////

//using the helper functions

const startArr = [
  [],
  ["2a", "2b"],
  ["3a", "3b", "3c"],
]

const longest = findLongest(startArr);

const paddedArray = startArr.map(arr => padStart(longest, "", arr));

const rotatedArray = transpose(paddedArray);

//format for betted display in the console:
const formattedArray = rotatedArray.map(arr => JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/"/g, "'"));

console.log(formattedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Args array of arrays to process
- Loop over arrays an index at a time and push into result arrays
- If *any* data exists in the *next* index keep processing.
- Return combined arrays
- `O(m*n)` complexity where m is the number of arrays and n the length of arrays

Code

```
const combineData = (...datas) => {
  let dataProcessed = false;
  let index = 0;
  const combinedData = [];

  while(!dataProcessed) {
    combinedData.push([]); // push new array for index
    dataProcessed = true; // assume data processed

    datas.forEach(data => {
      combinedData[index].push(data[index] ?? ""); // push value or ""
      if (data[index + 1]) dataProcessed = false; // check next index
    });

    index++; // bump index
  }

  return combinedData;
};
```

```js
const data1 = [];
const data2 = ["2a", "2b"];
const data3 = ["3a", "3b", "3c"];
const data4 = ["4a", "4b", "4c", "4d"];

const combineData = (...datas) => {
  let dataProcessed = false;
  let index = 0;
  const combinedData = [];

  while(!dataProcessed) {
    combinedData.push([]);
    dataProcessed = true;
    datas.forEach(data => {
      combinedData[index].push(data[index] ?? "");
      if (data[index + 1]) dataProcessed = false;
    });
    index++;
  }

  return combinedData;
};


console.log(JSON.stringify(combineData(data1, data2, data3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(combineData(data4, data1, data2, data3)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = ["2a", "2b"];
var arr3 = ["3a", "3b", "3c"];

var numberToIterate = Math.max(arr1.length, arr2.length, arr3.length);

var finalArr = [];
 

for(var i=0; i<numberToIterate; i++) {
var temp = [];
if(!arr1[i]){
  arr1[i] = "";
}
if(!arr2[i]){
  arr2[i] = "";
}
if(!arr3[i]){
  arr3[i] = "";
}
 temp.push(arr1[i]);
 temp.push(arr2[i]);
 temp.push(arr3[i]);
 
 finalArr[i] = temp;
}
```

Your result will be saved in finalArr.

Comment: I made same mistake at first for numberToIterate. If none of sub array lengths are greater than 2 it fails, Add `3` as argument in Math.max also

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. independent of the number of arrays and of any length.

```js
function createMatrix(...arrays){
const numOfArrays = arrays.length; // rows
const longestArray = Math.max.apply({},arrays.map(a => a.length)) //columns
let matrix = []

  for(let i =0; i<numOfArrays; i++){
      matrix[i] = matrix[i] ||[];
      for(let j=0; j<numOfArrays; j++){
          matrix[i].push(arrays[j] && arrays[j][i] || '')
      }
  }
  return matrix || [];
}

const result = createMatrix([1], [2, 22], [3, 33, 333])
const result2 = createMatrix([], [2, 22], [3, 33, 333], [4, 44, 444, 4444])
console.log(result)
console.log(result2)
```