# Google Script -> how to change this part of code, to get all columns?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

question is, how to **change** this part of the code, to **get all** columns from the **array** not only **[0,1,2,3]**

this is the codeline:

```
const new_table = [0,1,2,3].map(x => make_row_from_col(this_table, x)).join('\n');
```

and no, object.keys(this_table) does **NOT** work, because it does **NOT** give me all columns back only 4 rows are getting displayed smh.

whole script:

```
function Test() {
  
  const sSheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = sSheet.getSheetByName("Refinery");
  const table    = srcSheet.getRange("A:H").getValues(); // use "D2:M" if you have a header
  
  const values_C = table.filter(t => t[7] == "READY TO SELL").map(t => t[0]);
  const values_D = table.filter(t => t[7] == "READY TO SELL").map(t => t[1]);
  const values_E = table.filter(t => t[7] == "READY TO SELL").map(t => t[2]);
  const values_F = table.filter(t => t[7] == "READY TO SELL").map(t => t[3]);
 
  
  Logger.log(values_C)
  Logger.log(values_D)
  Logger.log(values_E)
  Logger.log(values_F)
  Logger.log(values_C.length)
      

      const this_table = [values_C,values_D,values_E,values_F];
      const make_row_from_col = (this_table, col) => this_table.map(x => x[col]).join("\t"+"\t"+"  |  "+"\t"+"\t");
      const new_table = Object.keys(this_table).map(x => make_row_from_col(this_table, x)).join('\n');
      
      Logger.log(new_table);
}
```

**THIS IS TABLE**
[image]

**this is LOG of this script and output that i want:**
[image]

Comment: Which columns are you talking about? Please consider clarifying where all this is coming from, and what exact data you want to retrieve (eg what is `values_C`, `values_D`, etc?).

Comment: so i updated it really hardcore even tho the info is not neccessary at all...

U see Logger.log(Values_C) ? There are 6 entries.

with "Object.keys(this_table)" in the last code line iam getting only 4 rows. why not 6 =?`

i hope you all understand now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

`Object.keys`, when applied to an array, will return an array with the indexes of this array. If you're using it on `this_table`, you'll only when an array with 4 items, since that's the length of `this_table`.

Because of this, you're only getting 4 rows for your "table".

#### Solution:

A easier and more efficient way to do this is to retrieve the values from your 4 desired columns at once, and use the different `join` on that:

```
const values = table.filter(t => t[7] == "READY TO SELL").map(t => t.slice(0,4));
const new_table = values.map(this_row => this_row.join("\t"+"\t"+"  |  "+"\t"+"\t")).join("\n");
```

If you wanted to retrieve the columns separately, though, I'd suggest transposing the resulting 2D array so that inner arrays are rows and not columns. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript) for an example on how to transpose an array (I don't think it makes much sense to do that, since `getValues()` by itself gives you the data organized in your desired way; also, even if the desired columns were not contiguous, you could easily filter your desired ones in a single 2D array).