# How to reduce an array of objects with two properties into two arrays, one for each property?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with two properties: `canais` and `topicos`:

```
 channel: Array(3)
    0: {canais: 'canal1', topicos: 'topico1'}
    1: {canais: 'canal2', topicos: 'topico2'}
    2: {canais: 'canal3', topicos: 'topico3'}
```

I want to split into two array of strings called canais and topicos:

```
canais : [ "canal1" , "canal2", "canal3" ];
topicos: [ "topico1" , "topico2", "topico3" ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```js
const canais = channel.map(item => item.canais)
const topicos = channel.map(item => item.topicos)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in multiple ways:

1. Map each element to a 2-element array `[canais, topicos]` and then transpose the result to get two arrays (here `original` is your array):

   ```
   const transpose = arr => arr[0].map((x, i) => arr.map(x => x[i]))
   const [canais, topicos] = transpose(original.map(a => [a.canais, a.topicos]))
   ```

   See also: [Transposing a 2D-array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript) which is the origin of the `transpose` function above.
2. Use a `forEach` loop and accumulate:

   ```
   const canais = []
   const topicos = []

   original.forEach(el => {
       canais.push(el.canais)
       topicos.push(el.topicos)
   })
   ```
3. Normal `for` loop and accumulate:

   ```
   const allCanais = []
   const allTopicos = []

   for (const {canais, topicos} of original) {
       allCanais.push(canais)
       allTopicos.push(topicos)
   }
   ```
4. Map two times (first extract all `el.canais` then all `el.topicos`), though this iterates twice over the data which is probably unneeded.

Answer (score -1):

If you need it to be dynamic, you can use a nested for loop to go through each item and create/add to arrays based on the key, then use an object to store each array of values.

```cs
let channelNames = {};
for(let c of channel){
    for(let key in c){
        if(!channelNames[key])
            channelNames[key] = [];
        channelNames[key].push(i[key]);
    }
}
```