# How to get 1 to n key value in an array of objects and push them to a new array?(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects,

```
[
 {trial1: 'a1', trial2: 'a2', trial3: 'a3'},
 {trial1: 'b1', trial2: 'b2', trial3: 'b3'},
 {trial1: 'c1', trial2: 'c2', trial3: 'c3'},
 ]
```

How do I get an array of arrays like this

```
[
 ['a1','a2','a3'],
 ['b1','b2','b3'],
 ['c1','c2','c3']
]
```

And also an array like this

```
[
 ['a1','b1','c1'],
 ['a2','b2','c2'],
 ['a3','b3','c3']
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map(Object.values)`:

```js
let data = [
 {trial1: 'a1', trial2: 'a2', trial3: 'a3'},
 {trial1: 'b1', trial2: 'b2', trial3: 'b3'},
 {trial1: 'c1', trial2: 'c2', trial3: 'c3'},
];

let result = data.map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

When you need to transpose:

```js
let data = [
 {trial1: 'a1', trial2: 'a2', trial3: 'a3'},
 {trial1: 'b1', trial2: 'b2', trial3: 'b3'},
 {trial1: 'c1', trial2: 'c2', trial3: 'c3'},
];

let result = data.map(Object.values);
result = result[0].map((_, i) => result.map(row => row[i]));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: How do i transpose this array

Comment: See [Transposing a 2D-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript). Also added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `map` and `Object.values` like this:

```js
const data = [
 {trial1: 'a1', trial2: 'a2', trial3: 'a3'},
 {trial1: 'b1', trial2: 'b2', trial3: 'b3'},
 {trial1: 'c1', trial2: 'c2', trial3: 'c3'},
 ];
const values = data.map(Object.values).map((item,i,self) => self.map(o => o[i]) );
console.log(values)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How do i transpose this array?

Comment: You're welcome, I edited my answer to transpose it.