# Google Apps Script - Transpose row to column with foreach

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to grab the data for my spreadsheet for the rows and headers based on a unique identifier. I can grab the data easily enough, put it into an array, but I cannot figure out how to transpose the data into a column. tried to sanitize so forgive if i missed something.

test sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/195YJwCj5KUljVnIldooQ-1DMEvw1b4vPj6-9Hc1xgJA/edit?usp=sharing

`function myFunction() {`

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`
  `var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();`
  `var uid = "2" //will eventually be dynamic, testing`
  `var allData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`
  `var temp = [];`
  `var dataTemp = []`
 
`var uidList = allData.getRange(1, 2, allData.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().map(function (r) { return r[0] })`
  `var uidIndex = uidList.indexOf(uid)`
  `var rowData = []`
  `var headers = []`
 
  `allData[0].forEach(function (r) { headers.push(r) })`
  `allData[0].forEach(function (x, i) {`
    `rowData.push(allData[uidIndex][i])`
  `})`
 
  `var combined = []`
  `combined.push(headers)`
  `combined.push(rowData)`
  
  `combined[0].forEach((x, i) => { //grab headers`
    `temp.push(combined[i][0])`
  `});`
  `combined[1].forEach((x, i) => { //grab data row`
    `dataTemp.push(combined[i][1])`
 
   `});`
  `// sheet.getRange(3,1,combined[0].length,combined.length).setValues(temp)`
 
`}`

Comment: In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17428587

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function, you have to pass your sheet for parametres and this function will transpose all google sheets.

```
function transposeSheet(sheet){
     var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      //Defining a blank array that can hold the result
      trans = [];
      //transpose the data stored in range variable
      for(var column = 0; column < range[0].length; column++){
        trans[column] = [];
        for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++){
          trans[column][row] = range[row][column];
        }
      }
      
      //Remove current data
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).clear();
      //printing values stored into trans variable on spreadsheet range
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, trans.length, trans[0].length).setValues(trans);
}
```