# select a column in xlsx file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, xlsx

I'm not trying to do anything fancy just select a column from an xlsx file as a variable. Well what I am trying to do overall is to take a list of numbers from a column and count the occurrences. I have two columns of numbers and want to count them seperately.

I am new to JS and all that I just wanted something that I thought would be easy to start with. Here is the code I have so far.

```
var xlsx =  require("xlsx");

var numbersWB = xlsx.readFile('lucky_for_life_numbers.xlsx');//imports the file
var ws = numbersWB.Sheets['Drawn'];//gets the Sheet 'Drawn' for the drawn numbers

var data = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);//converts the drawn column to something readable

console.log(data)//displays the data
```

And here is some sample data.

```
[
  { numbers: '6 - 8 - 14 - 25 - 42', lucky_numbers: 6 },
  { numbers: '1 - 12 - 17 - 28 - 44', lucky_numbers: 14 },
  { numbers: '1 - 10 - 24 - 26 - 30', lucky_numbers: 9 },
  { numbers: '5 - 23 - 26 - 29 - 36', lucky_numbers: 10 },
  { numbers: '8 - 15 - 19 - 46 - 47', lucky_numbers: 18 },
  { numbers: '2 - 6 - 24 - 32 - 39', lucky_numbers: 11 },
  { numbers: '4 - 5 - 35 - 37 - 48', lucky_numbers: 2 },
  //  ... 1319 more items
]
```

It's just like the power ball lottery - choose 5 numbers and a lucky number.

I have the data in an Excel spreadsheet and was looking to count the occurrences of the numbers by column, or lowest number to highest. For example:

```
Column 1 1:2 ,2:1, 4:1, 5:1, 6:1, 8:1  
Column 2 5:1, 6:1, 8:1......
lucky numbers 2:1, 6:1, 9:1.......
```

And so on

The 'numbers:' is a column and the 'lucky_numbers:' is a separate column in the spreadsheet but, this is how they are formatted as json data.

Here is a sample of the excel data

[Sample of the excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVGwf.png)

I didn't think it was going to be so hard to get this down. I did a little something like this in python and had pandas to help with all of the fun stuff.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is your friend.

Use `map` to isolate a column of the data e.g.

```js
const data = [
  { numbers: '6 - 8 - 14 - 25 - 42', lucky_numbers: 6 },
  { numbers: '1 - 12 - 17 - 28 - 44', lucky_numbers: 14 },
  { numbers: '1 - 10 - 24 - 26 - 30', lucky_numbers: 9 },
  { numbers: '5 - 23 - 26 - 29 - 36', lucky_numbers: 10 },
  { numbers: '8 - 15 - 19 - 46 - 47', lucky_numbers: 18 },
  { numbers: '2 - 6 - 24 - 32 - 39', lucky_numbers: 11 },
  { numbers: '4 - 5 - 35 - 37 - 48', lucky_numbers: 2 },
  //  ... 1319 more items
];

const lucky = data.map(d => d.lucky_numbers);

console.log(lucky);
```

To split the string array of numbers use `map` and `split`. Then to transpose the array to get a one row, per column, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript) (again using `map`):

```js
const data = [
  { numbers: '6 - 8 - 14 - 25 - 42', lucky_numbers: 6 },
  { numbers: '1 - 12 - 17 - 28 - 44', lucky_numbers: 14 },
  { numbers: '1 - 10 - 24 - 26 - 30', lucky_numbers: 9 },
  { numbers: '5 - 23 - 26 - 29 - 36', lucky_numbers: 10 },
  { numbers: '8 - 15 - 19 - 46 - 47', lucky_numbers: 18 },
  { numbers: '2 - 6 - 24 - 32 - 39', lucky_numbers: 11 },
  { numbers: '4 - 5 - 35 - 37 - 48', lucky_numbers: 2 },
  //  ... 1319 more items
];

const rowNumbers = data.map(d => d.numbers).map(str => str.split(" - "));
// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428587/transposing-a-2d-array-in-javascript
const colNumbers = rowNumbers[0].map((_, index) => rowNumbers.map(row => row[index]));

console.log(colNumbers);
```

To count the frequency of each unique number in an array use `Set` to get unique numbers and `map` with `filter` to get occurrences e.g.:

```js
var arr = [ 6, 1, 1, 5, 8, 2, 4 ]; // first 'column' of numbers
var uniques = [... new Set(arr)];
var freqs = uniques.map(n => ({[n]: arr.filter(k => k === n).length }));
console.log(JSON.stringify(freqs));
```