# JavaScript library for matrix-like transformations on 2D text arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

Is there a JavaScript library that will allow me to perform some matrix-like transformations (for example, rotating and mirroring) on 2D text arrays?  The arrays will contain characters and strings.

Comment: Try https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix

Comment: Check the libraries below.

Comment: Have any of these libraries been specifically tested to work with text arrays?  Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [math.js](http://mathjs.org/). It can do matrix operations.

Also check out [Sylvester](http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/) this I think might be easier to work with. It can even handle three dimensional space.

Here is a small example from it

```
var V1 = $V([3,4,5]);
var V2 = $V([9,-3,0]);

var d = V1.dot(V2);
// d is 15

var c = V1.cross(V2);
// c is the vector (15,45,-45)
```

There is also [webgl-mjs](https://code.google.com/p/webgl-mjs/) optimized for WebGL usage.

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170942/how-to-rotate-a-matrix-in-an-array-in-javascript) answer relating to rotation with your own function.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Google Closure library has AffineTransform.js.  If you don't want to include the whole closure library, I made a standalone version:

https://github.com/TheRoccoB/standalone-closure-graphics

Answer (score 0):

You could try text manipulation lib textillate.js
jschr.github.io/textillate