# How can I rotate a 4x8 grid represented as a single array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have rectangular 4x8 grid represented as an array of values in javascript:

```
var grid = [
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 0,    
];
```

How can I rotate this array -90 degrees to the left so that it then becomes an 8x4 grid?

I have tried toying with the solutions in other questions such as this one:

[How to rotate a matrix in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170942/how-to-rotate-a-matrix-in-an-array-in-javascript)

But the answers only deal with square grids.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried toying with the solution in this question, but it only works with square grids.  I'll add this to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170942/how-to-rotate-a-matrix-in-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Shouldn't it be a 2 dimensional array? As it has been defined, this is just a single row of 32 values.

Comment: It is represented as in javascript as a single array of 32 values, yes.  But I need to re-position those values as though the 'visual' representation were rotated to the left. i.e the value at row 1 column 4 becomes the value at row 1 column 1. Or in otherwords the value in the top right corner becomes the value in the top left.

Comment: @Gordo In the link you provided for the question you were investigating, you should just need to change the 'rowLength' to not use the square root of the total length. Make it a custom value and I think it should work.

Comment: @Aderis I tried that and it didn't appear to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var rows = 8;
var cols = 4;
var rotatedGrid = [];
var row = 0;
var col = 0;
for (col = cols - 1; col >= 0; col--)
{
    for (row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        rotatedGrid.push(grid[row * cols + col]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! and embarrassingly simple now that I've seen it written down.  Many thanks.