# how do I convert an array into values

Tags: google-apps-script

I have been doing some code with the help of stackoverflow people.
I have collect data, filter them, and then sort them.
but I get suck when I want to go to the next step.

Here is the code :

```
function FILL_PROJ_005() {


  var DATA_COLLECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");
  var PROJECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PROJECT");

  var DATA_COLLECTStartRow = 6;
  var DATA_COLLECTColumnCount = 1;
  var lrDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var rangeDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getRange(DATA_COLLECTStartRow,1,lrDATA_COLLECT-DATA_COLLECTStartRow,5);
  var DATA_COLLECT = rangeDATA_COLLECT.getValues();


  var DATA_FILTERED = DATA_COLLECT.filter(r => r[0] != ""); 
  

  var DATA_SORTED = DATA_FILTERED.sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1);


  var PROJECT_LIST = DATA_SORTED.getRange(1,1,1,1);

  Logger.log(PROJECT_LIST)


}
```

In the function  `var PROJECT_LIST = DATA_SORTED.getRange(1,1,1,1);` I would like to extract only some value of the `DATA_SORTED` ( at the end I need all the column "B", and `.getRange(1,1,1,1);` is just a first test.)

But I get this error message :  `TypeError: DATA_SORTED.getRange is not a function`

I understand that the result of `var DATA_SORTED` is an `array`, but how do I convert it again into values that I can continue to filter ?

I have try to use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but I felt to understand how to use it...

here is a sample of the data I'am working on :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | BELVEDERE MUSEUM | 31.5 | ANTHONY |
| 2D | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 161 | MAREIKE |
| PROJECT MANAGEMENT | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 22 | ANTHONY |
|  | DESIGN MUSEUM MÜNCHEN/DIE NEUE SAMMLUNG | 183 | ANTHONY |
| 2D | DHM BERLIN | 5 | MAREIKE |
|  | DHM BERLIN | 5 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW | 50 | MAREIKE |
| RECHERCHES | EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT WARSAW | 3 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ | 7 | ANTHONY |
|  | BERGBAUMUSEUM OELSNITZ | 7 | MAREIKE |
| 2D | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 48 | MAREIKE |
| COMMUNICATION | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 4 | MAREIKE |
|  | CHATEAUX DE BAVIERE | 52 | MAREIKE |

Comment: Range.getValue() or Range.getValues()

Comment: The range is not an array the data returns from getValues() is in a 2d array.

Comment: @Cooper, thanks, but what ever if I wrote   `var DATA_SORTED = DATA_FILTERED.Range.getValue();` or `var DATA_SORTED = DATA_FILTERED.Range.getValues();`, I get this message : `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getValue')`, I guess that it's in relation with the message in my post `TypeError: DATA_SORTED.getRange is not a function`, and with the fact that when I start to wrote .Ran... after my `var PROJECT_LIST = DATA_SORTED` the small pop up window never show me the possibility to clic on `.Range` or on `.Range.getValue` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recommendation:

After sorting the data, use `map()` to get column B values. In array, the index starts at 0 since you want to get the values of column B the function calls `d[1]`.

Since the result of PROJECT_LIST is in 1D array we need to turn it to 2D array to pass the data in the Sheets that’s why I create a `var PROJECT_LIST_FINAL` for that.

```
  function FILL_PROJ_005() {


  var DATA_COLLECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DATA_COLLECT");
  var PROJECTsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("PROJECT");

  var DATA_COLLECTStartRow = 6;
  var DATA_COLLECTColumnCount = 1;
  var lrDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getLastRow()+1;
  var rangeDATA_COLLECT = DATA_COLLECTsheet.getRange(DATA_COLLECTStartRow,1,lrDATA_COLLECT-DATA_COLLECTStartRow,5);
  var DATA_COLLECT = rangeDATA_COLLECT.getValues();
  var DATA_FILTERED = DATA_COLLECT.filter(r => r[0] != ""); 
  var DATA_SORTED = DATA_FILTERED.sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1);
  var PROJECT_LIST = DATA_SORTED.map(d => d[1]);
  var PROJECT_LIST_FINAL = [PROJECT_LIST];
  
   var transpose =[];
    for(var col = 0; col < PROJECT_LIST_FINAL[0].length; col++){
    transpose[col] = [];
    for(var row = 0; row < PROJECT_LIST_FINAL.length; row++){
      transpose[col][row] = PROJECT_LIST_FINAL[row][col];
    }
  }
  
  PROJECTsheet.getRange(1, 1, transpose.length, transpose[0].length).setValues(transpose);


}
```

### Reference:

- [map](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)

Comment: Let me know if this answers the issue you state on your question, or if there are some clarifications needed so that I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: it works greats ! thanks, but It turns the raw into column I think ! Is there anyway to flip/reverse the matrix easely ? I found   [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170942/how-to-rotate-a-matrix-in-an-array-in-javascript) but I guess there is an easy way !

Comment: There is something that I don't understand... I have test myself the`.map()` to try to solve my problem, but even with the link you send [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp), how can understand/discover that I have to wrote this `d => d[1]` between the `()`, there is no such an information on the page you share... Why the letter `d` ? what does `=>`mean ? thanks for your help !

Comment: @emilianoSala I'm glad that it is working as intended. Since we map it into an array it is expected behavior that it shows as column in Google Sheets however I updated my answer above and add something to convert rows to column. The for loop will iterate in each item to rotate it in rows.

Comment: In map() we have different parameters(value,index,array), `d` is what I use to label the current values, you can use other letter or word for that. `=>` is called function arrow, it is used to shorten the code instead of typing the whole function. You can also check this article about [map https://spreadsheet.dev/array-method-map-in-apps-script]

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAllTheValuesOnASheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const values = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values))
}

Execution log
10:40:15 AM Notice  Execution started
10:40:11 AM Info    [["COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5","COL6","COL7","COL8","COL9","COL10","COL11","COL12","COL13","COL14","COL15","COL16"],[5,7,6,9,20,10,6,7,11,19,6,10,9,8,11,18],[16,2,18,13,13,14,8,17,3,3,19,13,12,7,8,5],[9,3,20,17,17,13,3,16,19,10,9,12,12,15,18,0],[5,0,15,13,15,1,14,13,9,20,20,3,16,9,13,16],[7,10,16,8,20,6,0,20,15,13,19,8,5,7,2,3],[5,6,4,17,11,17,3,20,9,7,11,18,18,0,16,4],[17,19,9,10,12,9,3,9,10,16,4,18,9,20,5,18],[9,14,20,11,13,8,12,16,12,0,20,11,14,2,11,2],[12,15,4,6,20,8,8,17,19,10,4,19,10,11,12,0],[7,14,20,4,11,15,18,7,15,11,16,1,9,13,8,11],[19,15,6,20,10,4,6,2,20,2,17,18,15,14,14,2],[9,1,1,6,11,0,18,6,4,10,15,17,8,10,14,4],[0,18,13,9,11,5,8,2,4,17,6,3,11,4,0,20],[3,11,15,10,20,7,9,3,2,13,9,15,13,19,1,7],[9,12,4,5,4,0,14,19,20,17,6,1,13,2,20,6],[2,14,10,2,5,11,20,13,17,15,15,20,6,16,16,14],[3,7,19,13,15,16,6,17,8,4,5,7,14,5,13,10],[19,20,2,0,12,4,18,2,2,16,13,13,7,17,8,0],[10,9,5,20,5,9,6,15,16,18,7,7,20,13,7,12],[12,11,7,4,2,1,16,2,8,0,10,8,18,18,4,16],[8,16,3,3,19,3,15,17,12,7,20,18,16,12,0,14]]
10:40:17 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Hey ! not sure to understand if it's in relation with my question !