# PHP rotate matrix counter-clockwise

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

I am solving a larger problem and at one step I need to rotate a 2D array counter-clockwise.

So if I have this matrix:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6
```

After the rotation it will be:

```
4 4 6 6
3 3 5 5
2 2 4 4
1 1 3 3
```

I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3137413/407650) to rotate it clockwise:

```
<?php    
$a = array(array(1,2,3,4),array(5,6,7,8),array(9,0,1,2),array(3,4,5,6));
$b = array(); //result

while(count($a)>0)
{
    $b[count($a[0])-1][] = array_shift($a[0]);
    if (count($a[0])==0)
    {
         array_shift($a);
    }
}
?>
```

The thing is that this has to work even when `a` is uni-dimensional or has only one element.

So, `1 2 3 4` will become:

```
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$b = call_user_func_array(
    'array_map',
    array(-1 => null) + array_map('array_reverse', $a)
);
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out *how* it works.

Comment: I tried to figure out why the `array_map` with the `-1 => null` function  (or what actually the function is) groups nth elements from each row... http://ideone.com/ES75XJ Can you please explain that?

Comment: @Cristy see the example "[Creating an array of arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#example-4844)" in the manual. Your code essentially calls `array_map(null, [2,1], [3,2], [4,3])` which returns `[[2,3,4],[1,2,3]]`.

Comment: Interesting method! You can replace `array_map('array_reverse', $a)` with `$a` if you want to just rotate it clockwise, too.

Comment: @MattFletcher actually, replacing `array_map('array_reverse', $a)` with `$a` will rotate clockwise, but also reflect along the y axis. To only rotate CW, replace `array_map('array_reverse', $a)` with `array_reverse($a)`.

Answer (score 2):

Most concisely, transpose the array then reverse the first level.  Done.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mUhl3))

```
$a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6]];

var_export(array_reverse(array_map(null, ...$a)));
```

This approach will fail if the input array is a rectangular matrix with only one row.  This is due to how `array_map()` behaves with a `null` callback.

To stabilize the transposition, use nested loops ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TXb86))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $i => $v) {
        $result[$i][] = $v;
    }
}
var_export(array_reverse($result));
```

Or ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/keYdY))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach (array_reverse($row) as $i => $v) {
        $result[$i][] = $v;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that does both clockwise and counter-clockwise matrix rotation:

```
$a = array(array(1,2,3,4),array(5,6,7,8),array(9,0,1,2),array(3,4,5,6));
$b = $a; //result

$clockwise = false;  // toggle for clockwise / counter-clockwise

$rows = count($a);
$columns = ($rows > 0) ? count($a[0]) : 0;

for ($y = 0; $y < $rows; $y++) {
  for ($x = 0; $x < $columns; $x++) {
    $newX = $clockwise ? $y                  : ($rows - 1) - $y;
    $newY = $clockwise ? ($columns - 1) - $x : $x;
    $b[$newX][$newY] = $a[$x][$y];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive way:

```
            $m = array();
            $m[0] = array('a', 'b', 'c');
            $m[1] = array('d', 'e', 'f');
            $m[2] = array('g', 'h', 'i');
            $newMatrix = array();

            function rotateMatrix($m, $i = 0, &$newMatrix)
            {
                foreach ($m as $chunk) {
                    $newChunk[] = $chunk[$i];
                }
                $newMatrix[] = array_reverse($newChunk);
                $i++;

                if ($i < count($m)) {
                    rotateMatrix($m, $i, $newMatrix);
                }
            }

            rotateMatrix($m, 0, $newMatrix);
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($newMatrix);
            echo '<pre>';
```