# How does this code snippet rotating a matrix work?

Tags: python

While looking for a pythonic way to rotate a matrix, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496056/140367) answer. However there is no explanation attached to it. I copied the snippet here:

```
rotated = zip(*original[::-1])
```

How does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> lis = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

`[::-1]` reverses the list :

```
>>> rev = lis[::-1]
>>> rev
[[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
```

now we use `zip` on all items of the rev, and append each returned tuple to rotated:

```
>>> rotated = []
>>> for item in zip(rev[0],rev[1],rev[2]):
...     rotated.append(item)
...     
>>> rotated
[(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]
```

`zip` picks items from the same index from each of the iterable passed to it(it runs only up to the item with minimum length) and returns them as a tuple.

what is `*`:

`*` is used for unpacking all the items of `rev` to `zip`, so instead of manually typing
`rev[0], rev[1], rev[2]`, we can simply do `zip(*rev)`.

The above `zip` loop could also be written as:

```
>>> rev = [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> min_length = min(len(x) for x in rev)  # find the min length among all items
>>> rotated = []

for i in xrange(min_length):        
    items = tuple(x[i] for x in rev)  # collect items on the same index from each
                                      # list inside `rev`  
    rotated.append(items)
...     
>>> rotated
[(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Complementary to the explanations by Ashwini and HennyH, here's a little figure to illustrate the process.

[image]

1. First, the `[::-1]` slice operator reverses the list of list, taking the entire list (thus the first two arguments can be omitted) and using a step of `-1`.
2. Second, the `zip` function takes a number of lists and effectively returns a new list with rows and columns reversed. The `*` says that the list of lists is unpacked into several lists.

As can be seen, these two operations combined will rotate the matrix.

Answer (score 2):

For my explination:

```
>>> m = [['a','b','c'],[1,2,3]]
```

Which when pretty-printed would be:

```
>>> pprint(m)
['a', 'b', 'c']
[1, 2, 3]
```

Firstly, `zip(*m)` will create a list of all the *columns* in `m`. As demonstrated by:

```
>>> zip(*m)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

The way this works is `zip` takes *n* sequences and get's the `i-th` element of each one and adds it to a tuple. So translated to our matrix `m` where each *row* is represented by a list contained within `m`, we essentially pass in each row to `zip`, which then gets the 1st element from each row puts all of them into a tuple, then gets every 2nd element from each row etc... Ultimately getting every *column* in `m` i.e:

```
>>> zip(['row1column1','row1column2'],['row2column1','row2column2'])
[('row1column1', 'row2column1'), ('row1column2', 'row2column2')]
Notice that each tuple contains all the elements in a specific column
```

Now that would look like:

```
>>> pprint(zip(*m))
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
('c', 3)
```

So effectively, each *column* in `m` is now a *row*. Hoever it isn't in the correct order (try imagine in your head rotating `m` to get the matrix above, it can't be done). This why it's necessary to 'flip' the original matrix:

```
>>> pprint(zip(*m[::-1]))
(1, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(3, 'c')
```

Which results in a matrix which is the equivalent of `m` rotated - 90 degrees.