# rotate string in java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to rotate a string by ninety degrees
Exemple :

```
123 \n
456 \n
789 \n
```

shall become

```
741 \n
852 \n
963 \n
```

I did this

```
public String stringRotate(String string){

        String[] line= string.split("\n");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder builder3 = new StringBuilder();

        for (String s : line){

            builder.append(s.substring(0, 1));
            builder2.append(s.substring(1, 2));
            builder3.append(s.substring(2, 3));
        }

        builder.reverse().append("\n").append(builder2.reverse().append("\n").append(builder3.reverse().append("\n")));
        return builder.toString();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rotation r= new Rotation();
        String output = r.stringRotate("123" + "\n" + "456" + "\n" + "789");
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

but it's really bad because it's not dynamic and i create as many stringbuilder as line
Any suggestions for improvement please?

Comment: @PeterMmmm , degrees indeed , sorry for my mistake

Comment: what do you mean by 90 degree?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array. Should be able to apply this to your problem

Comment: @SimonPJ , thanks , i looked your link but it talks about matrix and i am using simple string

Comment: @vishram0709: Imagine the numbers connected by a chain, it is pulled to the right and the numbers rotate

Comment: @user902509: So put everything into an array then.. an array of strings. It doesn't matter the data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not questioning your approach to this probleme here. Maybe someone should :D Just trying to give advice on how to advance from where you are now.

To make it dynamically fit the size of your "string", you have to use an array of StringBuilders:

```
StringBuilder[] builders = new StringBuilder[line.length];
for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
    builders[i] = new StringBuilder();
}
```

To split your line into a one-character array you could use:

```
for (String s : line){
    String[] chars = s.split(""); //it might be better to use charAt() instead.
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        builders[i].append(chars[i]);
    }
}
```

I hope this gets you started.

Comment: thank you very much . I will start from your solutions . I almost got it . But the  line: String[] chars = s.split(""); add a empty data in the array . Why please ? Thanks again

Comment: solved , i use System.arraycopy() in order to remove the first empty element . Thank you very much man

Comment: @user902509 Glad I could help. I am abusing String.split a bit here. As mentioned in my code comment above it would be better to access the individual characters with s.charAt(i). Actually the StringBuilder certainly has an `append` method that accepts characters as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Rotate 
{
    public void rotate(char[][] original)
    {
        char[][] rotated=new char[3][3];
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            rotated[i][j]=original[j][i];

        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            System.out.print(rotated[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[][] original=new char[3][3];
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter values: ");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            original[i][j]=s.next().charAt(0);

        }
    }

    Rotate r=new Rotate();
    r.rotate(original);
}

}
```

I think this would help you.You can rotate it 90 degrees. but the M * n values must be same.hope this helps you.