# Rotating a 2D array using matrix transformation

Tags: arrays, matrix, rotation

I am writing a program that needs a nxn array to be rotated about it's center. Rotations are only at 90-degree angles.

What I do is I translate the origin to the center and perform the rotation, then translate it back again.

For example,a 3x3 array:

```
0 0 1
0 1 1
0 1 1
```

when rotated 90 degrees about it's center, becomes:

```
1 1 1
0 1 1
0 0 0
```

using (1,1) as it's center, then after getting the positions relative to the center, applying the rotation transformation. The problem is when I have an even-numbered dimension, a 4x4 array for example:

```
0 1 1 1
1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
```

What is it's center? Or rather, how do I correctly rotate the array using a transformation matrix?

**Edit**: assume that the arrays can contain anything, integers or maybe even objects

Comment: If these are truly matrices, why can't you use the transpose operator?

Comment: well, actually, I don't want this to be language-specific, and as efficient as possible

Comment: it doesn't need to be a matrix, but what I'm trying to do is to rotate objects in a grid

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20199933/2390644) shows conceptually what's going on.