# C++ Rotating Tetris Pieces

Tags: c++, rotation, tetris

In my program I am making the game Tetris! How could I rotate my char array piece? I know how to get the key syncs and everything. I could make each piece already rotated in the char, but is their an easier way? Here is my char array I'd use.

```
char block[4][5] = { 
      "     ",
      " x   ",
      " xxx ", 
      "     ", };
```

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array

Comment: @folkol, what would be the best way in my case from your link?

Comment: @ThatCoderBryan  what did you try so far ?

Comment: Nope, I got it! If you post that link as an answer and I vote it. Thank you:)