# Merge several arrays into one array

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I merge several arrays into one 2D array?

Given I have the following input:

```swift
var arr1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
var arr2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
var arr3 = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]
```

, I need to have the output like this:

```swift
[["1", "a", "aa"], ["2", "b", "bb"], ["1", "c", "cc"]]
```

Comment: You mean `["3", "c", "cc"]` for the last subarray?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Will the subarrays all be of the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to combine the three arrays into a 2D array, and then transpose it.

To transpose a 2D array, you can find many solutions in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920002/how-to-transpose-an-array-of-strings).

This uses Crashalot's solution in the comments:

```
fileprivate func transpose<T>(input: [[T]]) -> [[T]] {
    if input.isEmpty { return [[T]]() }
    let count = input[0].count
    var out = [[T]](repeating: [T](), count: count)
    for outer in input {
        for (index, inner) in outer.enumerated() {
            out[index].append(inner)
        }
    }
    return out

}

var arr1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
var arr2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
var arr3 = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]

transpose(input: [arr1, arr2, arr3])
```

If you want a more swifty `transpose`, you can use this (modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39891965/5133585)):

```
extension Collection where Self.Element: RandomAccessCollection {
    func transposed() -> [[Self.Iterator.Element.Iterator.Element]]? {
        guard Set(self.map { $0.count }).count == 1 else { return nil }

        guard let firstRow = self.first else { return [] }
        return firstRow.indices.map { index in
            self.map{ $0[index] }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All sub arrays have to have the same count

Comment: `input` has to have a matrix form. For the transposing to work, all inner arrays have to have the same number of elements.

Comment: @Carpsen90 But OP hasn't said anything about what happens when the arrays are off different lengths, so I didn't handle that. What do you think the output should be when they are different lengths?

Comment: Some padding with a default value might help (Speaking in math terms, all vectors (arrays) do have to have the same number of coordinates, it shouldn't even be allowed)

Comment: `guard input.dropFirst().first(where: {$0.count != input[0].count}) == nil else { fatalError("All arrays have to have the same number of elements") }`

Comment: @Cristik Found a more swifty version of `transpose`.

Comment: @Cristik It should be fine now. I simply rejected anything with subarrays of different lengths, since the OP did not say anything about subarrays having different lengths.

Answer (score 0):

This is a naive expressive way, if you like.

```
[arr1,arr2,arr3].reduce([[],[],[]]) { result, next -> [[String]] in
   return (0..<(next.count)).map{
         var array = Array.init(result[$0])
         array.append(next[$0]);
         return array
   }
}
```

or more directly:

```
[arr1,arr2,arr3].reduce(into: [[],[],[]]) { ( result : inout [[String]], next) in
 _ = (0..<(next.count)).map{ result[$0].append(next[$0]);}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A variadic, FP-style, solution, that can pack an arbitrary number of arrays:

```swift
func pack<T>(_ arrays: [T]...) -> [[T]] {
    guard !arrays.isEmpty else { return [] }
    let minCount = arrays.map(\.count).min()!
    return (0..<minCount).map { i in arrays.map { $0[i] } }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let arr1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
let arr2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
let arr3 = ["aa", "bb", "cc"]

let result = pack(arr1, arr2, arr3) 
// [["1", "a", "aa"], ["2", "b", "bb"], ["1", "c", "cc"]]

let anotherResult = pack(["firstName", "lastName"], ["John", "Doe"])
// [["firstName", "John"], ["lastName", "Doe"]]
```