# Rotating image 90 degree counter clockwise in Java

Tags: java

```
public static int[][] rotate(int[][] array){
    int height = array.length;
    int width = array[0].length;
    int[][] rotatedArray = array;

    for(int col = 0; col < width; col++){
        for(int row = 0; row < height; row++){
            rotatedArray[row][col] = array[col][row];
        }
    }
    return rotatedArray;
}
```

This is my code as method to rotate image 90 degree counter-wise, but it doesn't work. I have no idea how to arrange new rows and columns and rotate it properly, how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: What image? Represented in what way?

Comment: Just a random image and try to rotate it 90 degree counter-clockwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: You did not answer in what way the image is represented. Is the 2D array holding the pixels of the image?

Comment: Yes it is, and sorry I am just trying to write only method to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot user1803551! I figure it out with answer below! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `rotatedArray[row][col] = array[col][height - row - 1];`.

Also, you need to define `rotatedarray` as a new array. Right now, you're assigning it `array`, which means they are both referencing the same data.

Here's how you can do it:

```
public static int[][] rotate(int[][] array) {
    int height = array[0].length;
    int width = array.length;
    int[][] rotatedArray = new int[height][];

    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        rotatedArray[row] = new int[width];
        for(int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            rotatedArray[row][col] = array[col][height - row - 1];
        }
    }
    return rotatedArray;
}
```

Note that the height of the original array becomes the width of the new array and vice versa.

Comment: John, i kindly suggest that before guessing an answer try it yourself. You are responsible for what you answer, it is not up to the asker to decipher and debug your answer.

Comment: I have discovered a greater flaw in the original code an updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I draw a picture and finally understand it. :)

Comment: This really works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By transposing the row & column indices with `rotatedArray[row][col] = array[col][row]`, you are *mirroring* the image along the diagonal, instead of rotating it. Think about it - any entry where both indices are matching such as `array[0][0]` or `array[1][1]` is unchanged. That's not what you want!

I would recommend drawing a picture to see what pattern you see. You can start with very small examples, 2-by-2 or 3-by-3.

Comment: Thanks and I draw a picture, understanding it now.