# How can i print this in python using rows and cols?

Tags: python, puzzle

In python, I am really confused right now regarding how to apply rows and cols(edit: lists) in order to create this piece. I'm creating a class `Piece`, this has the four values (left, right, up, and down) and generate at random (with `randint(10, 99)`). I also want to be able to turn the piece for example:

```
piece after 0 turns :

   30
83 00 34
   25

piece after 1 turns :

   83
25 00 30
   34
```

Comment: what language are you writing code in?

Comment: by rows and cols i meant lists. more of how to use lists to format it in such a way. i have tried to write something but im a beginner

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/42519/4459346 (sort of a duplicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I wouldn't worry about rows and columns. My class would generate random values in its constructor method (`__init__`) to stick in a list (`vals = [top, right, bottom, left]`) and would have two methods for rotating left and right (`rotate_left` and `rotate_right`) and one method for getting the current list back (`get_vals`).

```
import random as rn

class Piece():

    def __init__(self):
        #vals = [top, right, bottom, left]        
        self.vals = [rn.randint(10,99) for _ in range(4)]
        self.n = 4

    def rotate_left(self):
        self.vals = [self.vals[i-self.n+1] for i in range(self.n)]

    def rotate_right(self):
        self.vals = [self.vals[i-1] for i in range(self.n)]

    def get_vals(self):
        return self.vals
```

Rotating with this list is simply shifting the values left or right by one index.

**Edit:** This is written with python 3.4 but it works with 2.7 too.

Comment: This was a fun little distraction, thanks for posting the problem! Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: thanks for answering. this looks good to me, it prints out the random values for top, left , right, bottom. im still trying to figure out how to format the values so that it looks sort of like the example i showed

Comment: I'm glad. Could you accept my solution so the question is marked as answered by clicking the check mark beside it?

Comment: Oops, I had a problem in my `rotate_right` method. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar implementation - except using generators and `itertools`.

What @wrkyle is doing is that he is replacing the values by constructing new lists. Imagine if you would like to rotate 1000000000 times. You'd have to construct a new list 1000000000 times. It's not very memory efficient.

For scalability, I propose that we generate an infinite sequence and just call the values as needed. I designed the `rotate` method so that it takes in an argument for the number of turns; this way the user does not have use any loops to cycle through the pieces - just calculate how many positions are to be shifted, and update the values once.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
from random import randint

class Piece:

    def __init__(self):
        self._values = cycle([randint(10, 99) for _ in range(4)])
        self._turns = 0

    def __str__(self):
        positions = list(islice(self._values, 0, 4))
        disp = (
            "piece after %s turns:" % (self._turns) + "\n\n" +
            "   %s   \n" % (positions[0]) +
            "%s 00 %s\n" % (positions[3], positions[1]) +
            "   %s   \n" % (positions[2])
        )
        return disp

    def rotate(self, num_turns, direction="right"):
        self._turns += num_turns
        if direction == "right":
            self._values = cycle(islice(self._values,
                                        2 + num_turns % 4,
                                        6 + num_turns % 4)
                                 )
        else:
            self._values = cycle(islice(self._values,
                                        0 + num_turns % 4,
                                        4 + num_turns % 4)
                                 )
```

Now if you run the following code, by rotating right -

```
p = Piece()

# rotate 4 times
for _ in range(4 + 1):
    print(p)
    p.rotate(1, direction="right")
```

You get:

```
piece after 0 turns:

   57   
86 00 89
   14   

piece after 1 turns:

   86   
14 00 57
   89   

piece after 2 turns:

   14   
89 00 86
   57   

piece after 3 turns:

   89   
57 00 14
   86   

piece after 4 turns:  # confirm it returns to original position

   57   
86 00 89
   14
```

Of course, you can change the default argument of the `rotate` method to "left" so that it rotates left.

Comment: Though I'm not exactly sure how efficient it is to loop the `next()`s like that. Theoretically, with a really huge `n = 10 ** 9` or something, this is far from optimized. It might be better off that you just slice it and cycle again, like: `x = cycle(islice(x, 0 + num_turns, 4 + num_turns))`

Comment: Hmm, I like the `__str__` method you used. I'd forgotten that was a thing.

Comment: Yep, turns out it's better to just make an infinite sequence again and cycle it through after `islic`-ing it. I've edited my implementation. Also, @wrkyle - it happens to the best of us. I'm a little salty you beat me by a few minutes to get best answer but kudos to you!