# Trying to swap values in 2d array inside nested for loops

Tags: c, arrays

I have been struggling with this for a while. Hopefully someone can help. Here goes. I have 2 dimensional array that is initialized in a nested for loop. If the dimensions of the array mod (%) 2 is even (d%2 == 0), I want to swap the element 2 and element 1 in the array matrix with one another.

Another idea I am struggling with is this, instead of perform a swap I could just simply explicit assign the 1 and 2 to the index of the array inside the for loop.

Here is the code I have so far.. I appreciate any inputs that will assist me to arriving at the right solution..

```
if (d % 2 == 0)
{        
    for (row_i = 0; row_i < d; row_i++)//loops through rows
    {
        for(col_j = 0; col_j < d; col_j++) //loops through column
        {
            board[row_i][col_j] = multi_dim--;
            if(board[row_i][col_j] == 2 && board[row_i][col_j] == 1)
            {
                int hold = board[d][d -2];
                board[d][d - 2] = board[d][d - 1];
                board[d][d - 1] = hold;
            }
            printf(" %2d ", board[row_i][col_j]);
        }
        printf("\n");  
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite get the logic you're describing.  Is this to rotate a matrix? 

Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 1):

```
if(board[row_i][col_j] == 2 && board[row_i][col_j] == 1)
```

This test is always false.  You're asking the same variable 'board[row_i][col_j]' to be 2 and 1 at the same time.

Comment: I see. Would having a nested if statement be a better option..

if(board[row_i][col_j] == 2)
{
    if(board[row_i][col_j] == 2)
    {
        int hold = board[d][d -2];
        board[d][d - 2] = board[d][d - 1];
        board[d][d - 1] = hold;    
    }
}

Comment: To be honest I don't quite understand the problem you're trying to solve.  I just noticed the logic problem and pointed it out.  Your 'better' option is no different.  Nesting if's is the same as an '&&' since it only gets to the inner code if both conditions are true.

Comment: Oh ok.. So the for loops are supposed to iterate through and initialize the array boards[][] with the values of multi_dim, which is initialized (d*d) - 1. There is a condition is the that check if d%2 == 0. if that is true, I want to swap array index that is initialize with the value 2 with the array index that is initialized with the value 1. That is what I am having trouble with

Comment: @Barinuadum Emmanuel Bariyiga - Your phrase _to swap array index_ is unintelligible. Add the desired contents of `board` for d = 2 to your question as an example.