# Switch Rows and Columns 2d Array

Tags: java

I want to swap Columns and Rows in a 2D array.

My problem is that I want the Variable "oldField" to save the oldField. The Variable I think is Pointing on the same Object as newField and so it get´s changed even tho I dont want that.

Id like to know how I can save the Variable oldField independent

```
public int[][] swapMatrix(int[][] pField) { // swaps the rows and columns in
                                            // a Field
    int[][] oldField = pField.clone();
    int[][] newField = pField.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
        for (int j = (newField.length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
            newField[i][(newField.length - 1) - j] = oldField[j][i];
        }
    }
    return newField;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

When you copy in 1-D array with primitive value like int then the new array and content copy to it and there is no reference.

```
 int row1[] = {0,1,2,3};
    int row2[] =  row1.clone();
    row2[0] = 10;
    System.out.println(row1[0] == row2[0]); // prints false
```

but for 2-D array the content is object and clone method only do shallow copy not create new content if object is there .For your requirement you need to do deep copy.

```
int table1[][]={{0,1,2,3},{11,12,13,14}};
    int table2[][] = table1.clone();
    table2[0][0] = 100;
    System.out.println(table1[0][0] == table2[0][0]); //prints true
```

Answer (score 1):

this code solves your problem:

```
public class SwapRowsAndColumns {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] someMatrix = new int[2][3];

        someMatrix[0][0] = 1;
        someMatrix[0][1] = 2;
        someMatrix[0][2] = 3;

        someMatrix[1][0] = 4;
        someMatrix[1][1] = 5;
        someMatrix[1][2] = 6;

        printMatrix(someMatrix);
        int[][] invertedMatrix = swapMatrix(someMatrix);
        printMatrix(invertedMatrix);

    }

    private static int[][] swapMatrix(int[][] pField) {

        int originalTotalRows = pField.length;
        int originalTotalColumns = pField[0].length;

        int[][] newMatrix = new int[originalTotalColumns][originalTotalRows];

        for(int i=0; i< originalTotalRows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < originalTotalColumns; j++){
                newMatrix[j][i] = pField[i][j];
            }
        }
        return newMatrix;
    }

    private static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
        int totalRows = matrix.length;
        int totalColumns = matrix[0].length;

        for(int i=0; i< totalRows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< totalColumns; j++){
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ty, I copied the Matrix with 2x for(){...} now it works just fine