# rotate Image List comprehension

Tags: python, matrix, in-place

While solving a problem on matrix rotation I came across a solution .The question asks to rotate the matrix by 90 degrees in place.

```
def rotateImage(a):
    rows = len(a)
    cols = len(a[0])
    a=a[::-1]
    return [[m[i] for m in  a] for i in range(cols)]
```

Can someone help me in breaking down this list comprehension to regular for-loop and understand the flow of the program

Answer (score 1):

You have a *nested* list comprehension, an outer list comprehension creating a new list for every iteration.

You can deconstruct any list comprehension by reading the `for` and `if` components from left to right as nested blocks. *Everything* before the first `for` is the expression that produces the elements of the list.

So the basic structure is:

```
[<expression> for <targets> in <iterable> <optionally more if and for>]
```

which can always be converted to a regular loop with:

```
_result = []
for <targets> in <iterable>:
    <optionally more if and for blocks, add a new level each time>
        _result.append(<expression>)
```

I added in `_result` as an explicit name for the list that is produced; note that the result of `<expression>` is appended to it each iteration.

Your example breaks down to **two** list comprehensions. The outer loop is this:

```
[[m[i] for m in  a] for i in range(cols)]
# \              /      |     \       /
#   <expression>    <targets>  <iterable>
```

So the `[m[i] for m in  a]` is the expression here! Writing this out that becomes:

```
_result_outer = []
for i in range(cols):
    _result_outer.append([m[i] for m in  a])
```

The inner list comprehension is straightforward:

```
_result_inner = []
for m in a:
    _result_inner.append(m[i])
```

If you put these two together you get:

```
_result_outer = []
for i in range(cols):
    _result_inner = []
    for m in a:
        _result_inner.append(m[i])
    _result_outer.append(_result_inner)
```

Now you can see that the `i` target from the *outer* loop, is used each time in the *inner* loop. Because `i` loops over the number of columns, but `m` is a row, this produces first a list with all the values from the very first column, then the second column, and then the third, etc.

The line before the list comprehension *reversed* the rows:

```
a = a[::-1]
```

This takes all rows, and goes from the last to the first (stepping backwards, with a `-1` step size). This makes it so that the list comprehension loops over the rows in reverse order.

The code can be cleaned up and improved a little. The `rows` variable is never used, for example, and we can use the [`reversed()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) to loop over a list in reverse order without creating a copy:

```
def rotateImage(a):
    cols = len(a[0])
    return [[m[i] for m in reversed(a)] for i in range(cols)]
```

Another method of transposing a matrix (moving columns to rows) is using the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with all the rows applied as separate arguments, with the `*<expression>` call syntax:

```
def rotateImage(a):
    return [list(r) for r in zip(*reversed(a))]
```

This still uses a list comprehension, because `zip()` produces an *iterable object*, not a list, and each time you iterate you get a tuple. The above list comprehension converts the whole result back to a list of lists.

If you want to do this *in place*, I suggest you read the very excellent answer Jack wrote on rotating a matrix with Python; their explanation of how to code this is second to none: [How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array/35438327#35438327)

Answer (score 0):

The `a=a[::-1]` is simply a in reverse. The list comprehension is:

```
res = []
for i in range(cols):
    tmp = []
    for m in a:
        tmp.append(m[i])
    res.append(tmp)
return res
```

****EDIT****

What is basically happening here is the for each column index `i` the algorithm goes through all the rows `m` (form last to first) and appends the `m[i]` (the i'th value in the m'th row) to `tmp`, which is then appended as a row, to `res`. So each reversed column is added as a row to `res`.

So for a matrix like:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 0 4
```

The first inner loop iteration will result in `tmp=[9, 5, 1]`

Comment: Thanks so much.Can you suggest a way in which we can implement a matrix rotation in place using for-loop

Comment: @HasanJunaid: [How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](//stackoverflow.com/a/35438327) covers this in more detail than you could ever wish for.

Comment: @HasanJunaid I am not sure what you are further asking, but I edited my answer to help you understand the algorithm's flow.