# How to Rotate and Flip a 2D char Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

How can I rotate and flip the 2D char array so the letters display in different order?

```
char[,] array = new char[6,4] { 
    { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
    { 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H' },
    { 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L' },
    { 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P' },
    { 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T' },
    { 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X' }
};
```

**6x4 Matrix**

```
Orig.       90°             180°        270°            Flip H      Flip V
A B C D     U Q M I E A     X W V U     D H L P T X     D C B A     U V W X
E F G H     V R N J F B     T S R Q     C G K O S W     H G F E     Q R S T
I J K L     W S O K G C     P O N M     B F J N R V     L K J I     M N O P
M N O P     X T P L H D     L K J I     A E I M Q U     P O N M     I J K L
Q R S T                     H G F E                     T S R Q     E F G H
U V W X                     D C B A                     X W V U     A B C D
```

---

After the array has been rotated, I want to `String.Join()` all the rows into a single line for another use.

So if you were to flip the array 90° and `String.Join()`
`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX` would appears as `UQMIEAVRNJFBWSOKGCXTPLHD`.

---

**Example**

Here is a rotation method 90°.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42535/6806643

```
char[,] rotated = RotateMatrix(array, 4);


static char[,] RotateMatrix(char[,] matrix, int n) {
    char[,] ret = new char[n, n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            ret[i, j] = matrix[n - j - 1, i];
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

But I can only get it to display up to 4 columns

```
M I E A
N J F B
O K G C
P L H D
```

when it should be 6

```
U Q M I E A
V R N J F B
W S O K G C
X T P L H D
```

http://rextester.com/BAMTJ38063

Comment: The code you included is for a square 2d array, you'll need to updated it to work with a rectangular one.

Comment: How is this related to WPF?

Comment: @Clemens I had WPF grid in my original question but changed it. I'll remove the tag.

Comment: @Odrai As ameer pointed out, that seems to be for a square array. How can I change it to a rectangular?

Comment: @MattMcManis Take a look at other answers from the linked (duplicate) question - not just accepted.

Comment: FYI, standard matrix notation is rows x columns, so your original matrix is 6x4.

Comment: [There](https://github.com/leofun01/Transformer/blob/4402eb577ce84c177ef7e1d6b8df597e09a4f63f/DotNetTransformer/Extensions/ArrayExtension.cs#L16) exist an algorithm that allows to rotate and flip 2d array. Also you can use [this](https://github.com/leofun01/Transformer/blob/3aff9fa0563f6cfc2f1296278fac7a7015c6c18a/DotNetTransformer/Extensions/ArrayExtension.cs#L49) algorithm with System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.