# Is there any method to write csv column wise by using "|" as separator in java

Tags: java, arraylist, opencsv

I have `List<ArrayList<String>>` objects and i want to write them into csv file column by column in java.

```
List<ArrayList<String>> contains 

[[fileName, abc.sldprt, pqr.sldprt, jku.sldprt, cmx.sldprt, abc.sldprt],
[cadName, abc.sldprt, pqr.sldprt, jku.sldprt, cmx.sldprt, abc.sldprt],
[number, abc.sldprt, pqr.sldprt, jku.sldprt, cmx.sldprt, abc.sldprt],
[folder_Id, 098123, 098124, 094123, 0981290, 09812354],
[Directory_Path, 098123, 098124, 094123, 0981290, 09812354],
[wC_State, Working, WIP, Released, Development, Working],
[legacy_Path, C:\WC, C:\WC, C:\WC, C:\WC, C:\WC],
[reverified, Empty, Empty, Empty, Yes, Empty],
[createdBy, 12132019, 12092019, 12072019, 12132018, 12132019],
[originDate, 12132019, 12092019, 12072019, 12132018, 12132019],
[iteration, 2, 8, 13, 19, 3],
[shouldImport, True, True, True, True, True],
[Mymap, True, True, True, True, True],
[YourMap, True, True, True, True, True]]
```

Till now i have tried below code

```
String csv = "C:\\Users\\Output.csv";
        CSVWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv),'|',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
            for(ArrayList<String> each: databaseColListHeaderChange){
                writer.writeNext(each.toArray(new String[each.size()]));
            }
            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm getting the data row wise in the csv file.
is there any way to write ArrayList inside list column wise into csv file

Right now i get the csv file in following format

```
fileName|abc.sldprt|pqr.sldprt|jku.sldprt|cmx.sldprt|abc.sldprt
cadName|abc.sldprt|pqr.sldprt|jku.sldprt|cmx.sldprt|abc.sldprt
number|abc.sldprt|pqr.sldprt|jku.sldprt|cmx.sldprt|abc.sldprt
folder_Id|098123|098124|094123|0981290|09812354
Directory_Path|098123|098124|094123|0981290|09812354
wC_State|Working|WIP|Released|Development|Working
legacy_Path|C:\WC|C:\WC|C:\WC|C:\WC|C:\WC
reverified|Empty|Empty|Empty|Yes|Empty
createdBy|12132019|12092019|12072019|12132018|12132019
originDate|12132019|12092019|12072019|12132018|12132019
iteration|2|8|13|19|3
shouldImport|True|True|True|True|True
Mymap|True|True|True|True|True
YourMap|True|True|True|True|True
```

I need the data in following format

```
fileName|cadName|number|folder_Id|Directory_Path
abc.sldprt|abc.sldprt|abc.sldprt|098123|098123
pqr.sldprt|pqr.sldprt|pqr.sldprt|098124|098124
jku.sldprt|jku.sldprt|jku.sldprt|094123|094123
cmx.sldprt|cmx.sldprt|cmx.sldprt|0981290|0981290
abc.sldprt|abc.sldprt|abc.sldprt|09812354|09812354
...so on all the list
```

please if any suggestion or help?

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your data into a map where key will be your first arrayList entry and value will be the rest of the list.

```
{
 fileName=[abc.sldprt, pqr.sldprt, jku.sldprt, cmx.sldprt, abc.sldprt],
 cadName=[abc.sldprt, pqr.sldprt, jku.sldprt, cmx.sldprt, abc.sldprt],
...
}
```

and then use the map keys as headers

Comment: i did normalize the data Map<String, ArrayList<String>> ,here i wanted to know how to use map keys as header or is there any peace of code for reference?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to think through the steps that *you* would take if *you* were writing out the content of this array of arrays by hand.

The bare bones of this, java-flavoured pseudocode:

```
for(int column=0; column<numColumns; column++) {
   for(int row=0; row<numRows; row++) {
      output content[row][column];
      output "|" when necessary
   }
   output newline
}
```

The key difference between this and what you've already done is that you're flipping the order of `content[column][row]` to `content[row][column]`.

Note that if this isn't an academic exercise, you should use a library such as [Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) to read/write CSV-like data, because there can be subtle issues, and they've been solved.