# swapping list variables in nested loop unexpected result (single array?)

Tags: python, list, algorithm

If i have a multidimensional array that is a square like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

And I want to turn it 90 degrees clockwise like this:

```
[[7, 4, 1],
 [8, 5, 2],
 [9, 6, 3]]
```

I can print out the changed square like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a),0,-1):
        print(f"{a[j-1][i]}",end=",")
    print()
```

The output is:

```
7,4,1,
8,5,2,
9,6,3,
```

But if I tried to re-arrange the python list in place, I get the wrong order.

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    x = 0
    for j in range(len(a),0,-1):
        # pythonism to swap w/o temp variable         
        a[i][x],a[j-1][i] = a[j-1][i],a[i][x]
        x += 1
        
print(a)
```

The output is:

```
[[3, 6, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 4, 7]]
```

To clarify, so far my thinking was that in order to do this we make the following transformation:

```
a0 a1 a2 => c0 b0 a0
b0 b1 b2 => c1 b1 a1
c0 c1 c2 => c2 b2 a2
```

Because of the comments I see that the issue was because I am changing the array cells more than once as I move it.

What I am trying to do is change the square not more than using O(1) additional memory. Is there a way to do this without using a new array?

Comment: [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to actually [check what happens](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) when the code runs, for example by using a debugger or `print`ing some values? We do not provide a debugging service here. The problem here is purely one of logic, not programming.

Comment: Hint: you know how, in other languages that don't have that "pythonism to swap w/o temp variable", you need the temp variable and can't just do two assignments? **Why is that**? It's because, otherwise, the first assignment *will affect what the second one does*, right? Think carefully about how, and then consider how the *same reasoning applies* to attempting multiple swaps of elements within the same data structure.

Comment: One simple option to avoid changing much of your code is to `deepcopy` a: `b = copy.deepcopy(a)` then use this as source in your loop

Comment: I dunno why we're giving hints here but it seems the issue is that you didn't take into account that you're doing your operations on the list while you're changing it at the same time. When you do print(a) in the second for loop, you can see that the 7 is transposed to the first spot correctly (when i = 0 and j = len(a) and x = 0). But later when i = 0, j = 1 and x = 3, you end up moving the 7 somewhere else again. What you could do use `b = copy.deepcopy(a)` as the comment above me suggested and then perform all of your operations on b.

Comment: Related question: [How do you rotate a two dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519/how-do-you-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 1):

Consider for example the four corner values `1`, `3`, `7`, `9`.
To accomplish the rotation, `1` must move to where `3` is, `3` to `9`, `9` to `7` and `7` to `1` - simultaneously.

**Just like how** swapping two elements by serial assignment does not work:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a = b # `a` becomes 2
b = a # oops, `b` doesn't become 1, because this uses the new `a`
```

similarly the 4-way swap cannot be accomplished by repeated, naive swapping of element pairs:

```
a, b, c, d = 1, 3, 9, 7 # the values to swap, clockwise around the original
a, b = b, a # put the 1 in the right place
b, c = c, b # oops, moved the 1 again
```

Regardless of the order in which the swaps are attempted, problems will occur if we do not account for the effect of previous swaps.

The simplest and most understandable way to effect the swap is to just use Python's trick for all four elements at once:

```
b, c, d, a = a, b, c, d
```

Given a proper understanding of how the original swap trick works, it is both obvious to try this, and obvious how it works.

In general, an odd-sized square can be decomposed into triangles like so:

```
aaaaaaaab
caaaaaabb
ccaaaabbb
cccaabbbb
cccc*bbbb
ccccddbbb
cccddddbb
ccddddddb
cdddddddd
```

and an even-sized square like so:

```
aaaaaaab
caaaaabb
ccaaabbb
cccabbbb
ccccdbbb
cccdddbb
ccdddddb
cddddddd
```

So the rotation is simply a matter of setting up loops to iterate over the `a` region, find the corresponding `b`/`c`/`d` positions for a corresponding `a`, and doing the swap. This is left as an exercise.

Comment: I agree with almost everything you say, except the advice to cut the square into four triangles. Cutting it into 4 rectangles instead seems much easier: `aabb,aabb,ddcc,ddcc` for an even-sized square and `aaabb,aaabb,dd*bb,ddccc,ddccc` for an odd-sized square. Also, if the list of lists turns out to be a rectangle instead of a square, cutting it into four triangles becomes even harder, whereas cutting it into 4 rectangles remains exactly as easy.

Comment: True, not sure how I didn't think of that. I'll edit on that basis later.

Answer (score 1):

First comment: in your loops, you always loop over `range(0, len(a))`. This assumes that the height and width are both equal to `len(a)`, in other words this assume that `a` is a square. However, your task makes sense for all rectangles, not just for squares. So, it is better not to make this assumption. Vertical indices for `a` should loop over `range(0,len(a))`, but horizontal indices for `a` should loop over `range(0, len(a[0]))`.

Second comment: rather than `for j in range(len(a),0,-1): print(a[j-1][i],end=",")`, I recommend `for j in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1): print(a[j][i],end=",")`

Now on to actually performing the task.

Since your printing-loop works, you can turn it into a function that returns a new list of lists, by "printing into a list", using `list.append` instead of `print`. Just replace:

- `print(x, end='')` with `row.append(x)`;
- `print()` with `result.append(row); row=[]`:

```py
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] # square
b = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]] # non-square rectangle

def rotate_clockwise_append(a):
    height, width = len(a), len(a[0])
    result = []
    row = []
    for i in range(0,width):
        for j in range(height-1,-1,-1):
            row.append(a[j][i])
        result.append(row)
        row = []
    return result

print(rotate_clockwise_append(a)) # [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
print(rotate_clockwise_append(b)) # [[9, 5, 1], [10, 6, 2], [11, 7, 3], [12, 8, 4]]
```

In python, it's always possible to build a list using a list comprehension, rather than using `.append` in a loop:

```py
def rotate_clockwise_listcomp(a):
    height, width = len(a), len(a[0])
    return [
        [a[j][i] for j in range(height-1,-1,-1)]
        for i in range(0,width)
    ]

print(rotate_clockwise_listcomp(a)) # [[7, 4, 1], [8, 5, 2], [9, 6, 3]]
print(rotate_clockwise_listcomp(b)) # [[9, 5, 1], [10, 6, 2], [11, 7, 3], [12, 8, 4]]
```

You can also use builtin functions to do the reversal operations for you:

```py
def rotate_clockwise_builtin(a):
    return list(zip(*reversed(a)))  # or list(map(list,zip(*reversed(a)))) if you're afraid of a list of tuples

print(rotate_clockwise_builtin(a)) # [(7, 4, 1), (8, 5, 2), (9, 6, 3)]
print(rotate_clockwise_builtin(b)) # [(9, 5, 1), (10, 6, 2), (11, 7, 3), (12, 8, 4)]
```

If you deal with rectangle arrays a lot, it is often recommended to use numpy rather than builtin python lists:

```py
import numpy as np

def rotate_clockwise_numpy1(a):
    return np.flip(a, axis = 0).T  # flip vertically, then transpose

def rotate_clockwise_numpy2(a):
    return np.flip(np.transpose(a), axis=1)  # transpose, then flip horizontally

print(rotate_clockwise_numpy1(a))
# [[7 4 1]
#  [8 5 2]
#  [9 6 3]]
print(rotate_clockwise_numpy1(b))
# [[ 9  5  1]
#  [10  6  2]
#  [11  7  3]
#  [12  8  4]]

print(rotate_clockwise_numpy2(a))
# [[7 4 1]
#  [8 5 2]
#  [9 6 3]]
print(rotate_clockwise_numpy2(b))
# [[ 9  5  1]
#  [10  6  2]
#  [11  7  3]
#  [12  8  4]]
```

Comment: I updated my question. I am interested only in squares. I should have clarified that my interpretation of the problem statement was that it is possible to do this with no additional arrays. I wonder if that is true.

Comment: @Lucky Yes it is, see KarlKnechtel's answer.